# PowerShell: Capture the output from external process that writes to stderr in a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to capture the output of a external process into a variable (string), so I can do some processing on that.

The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097354/how-do-i-capture-the-output-into-a-variable-from-an-external-process-in-powershe) works nicely as long as the process writes to stdout. However, if the process fails, it writes to stderr. I'd like to capture this string too, and I can't figure out how to do it.

Example:

```
$cmdOutput = (svn info) | out-string
```

This works, unless SVN has an error. If an error occured, SVN writes to stderr, and `$cmdOutput` is empty.

How do I capture the text written to stderr in a variable in PowerShell ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cmdOutput = svn info 2>&1
```

Comment: That works. Could you explain why (what does the syntax mean) ?

Comment: @driis 1 is standard output descriptor and 2 is error output. With 2>&1 we are redirecting error to standard output. If it works, you should accept it as answer. Even in your other question that you have linked to.

Answer (score 7):

To complement [manojlds' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185731/45375) with an overview:

<sup>To briefly explain redirection expression `2>&1`:

`2>` redirects (`>`) PowerShell's *error* output stream, whose number is `2` (and which maps onto stderr) into (`&`) PowerShell's *success* output stream, whose number is `1` (and maps onto stdout).

Run [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) to learn more.</sup>

**Character-encoding caveat**, which applies to all solutions below:

- Capturing output from external programs or piping it to another command invariably subjects it to *decoding into .NET strings*, which can reveal a mismatch between the actual character encoding a given program uses and the one PowerShell uses for decoding, as reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which itself defaults to the console's active code page (as reported by `chcp`).
- Thus, you may have to (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the actual encoding to ensure correct interpretation of non-ASCII characters in the output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for details.

#### Capturing stdout and stderr output *combined*, as a merged stream:

---

**As a collection of output lines *as strings*, without the ability to tell which line came from what stream:**

Using the platform-native shell to perform the merging *at the source* makes PowerShell only see *stdout* output, which, as usual, it collects in an array of strings.

In the following examples, the commands each create both stdout and stderr output.
All commands use PSv3+ syntax for convenience and brevity.

*Windows* example:

```bash
# Collect combined output across both streams as an array of
# strings, where each string represents and output line.
# Note the selective quoting around & and 2>&1 to make sure they
# are passed through to cmd.exe rather than PowerShell itself interpreting them.
$allOutput = cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch '2>&1'
```

*Unix* example (PowerShell Core):

```bash
# sh, the Unix default shell, expects the entire command as a *single* argument.
$allOutput = sh -c '{ date; ls /nosuch; } 2>&1'
```

Note:

- You do need to call the platform-native shell explicitly (`cmd /c` on Windows, `sh -c` on Unix), which makes this approach less portable.
- You will not be able to tell from the resulting array of lines which line came from what stream.
  See below for how to make this distinction.

---

**As a mix of *string* lines (from stdout) and `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` "lines" (from stderr):**

By using *PowerShell's* `2>&1` redirection, you also get a single stream of lines representing the merged stdout and stderr streams, but the *stderr* lines aren't captured as *strings*, but rather as [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances.

<sup>**Caveat**: A **bug** in Windows PowerShell v5.1 (since fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)) results in unexpected behavior when you redirect PowerShell's error stream with `2>` while `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is in effect - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002).</sup>

This gives you the flexibility to distinguish between stdout and stderr lines by examining the data type of each output object.
On the flip side, you may have to convert the stderr lines to strings.

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the different data types are not obvious when you simply *display* the captured output, but you can tell by reflection:

```bash
# Let PowerShell merge the streams with 2>&1, which captures
# stdout lines as strings and stderr lines as [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] 
# instances.
$allOutput = cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch 2>&1
```

Inspect the result (`%` is a built-in alias for the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet):

```bash
PS> $allOutput | % GetType | % Name
String
String
String
String
String
String
ErrorRecord
```

As you can see, the last array element is an error record, which represent the single `File Not Found` stderr output line produced by the `dir \nosuch` command.

Note:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, when you output the captured output to the console, the `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances actually rendered in the same format as PowerShell errors, perhaps making it appear as if an error had occurred *then*.
  In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, these error records print just their message, i.e., the contents of the original stderr line, and *visually* you can't tell that an error record rather than a string is being printed.

To **convert all captured output to *strings*** (for brevity, `%`, the built-in alias of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) is used; in effect, the `.ToString()` method is called on each output object):

```bash
$allOutput = cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch 2>&1 | % ToString
```

To **filter out the stderr lines** (and converting them to strings in the process; for brevity, `?`, the built-in alias of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) is used):

```bash
$allOutput = cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch 2>&1
$stderrOnly = 
  $allOutput | 
  ? { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] } | 
  % ToString
```

---

#### Capturing stderr output *separately*:

---

**Using a temporary *file***:

As of PSv5.1, the only direct way to capture stderr output in isolation is to use redirection `2>` with a *filename* target; i.e., to capture stderr output - as text - in a *file*:

```bash
$stderrFile = New-TemporaryFile # PSv5+; PSv4-: use [io.path]::GetTempFileName()
$stdoutOutput = cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch 2>$stderrFile
$stderrOutput = Get-Content $stdErrFile
Remove-Item $stderrFile
```

Clearly, this is cumbersome and also slower than in-memory operations.

---

**Using the PSv4+ intrinsic [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) array method**:

The PSv4+ intrinsic [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) allows you to split a collection in two, based on whether the elements pass a Boolean test or not:

```bash
 # Merge the streams first, so that stderr too goes to the success stream, 
 # then separate the objects in the merged stream by type.
 $stdoutOutput, [string[]] $stderrOutput = 
   (cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch 2>&1).Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split')
```

Note:

- The `[string[]]` type constraint converts the `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances that make up the stderr output to an array of strings.
- The two output objects emitted by `.Where()` are *always* collections (array-like, of type [`[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection-1)), even if they contain only *one* element.
- While this approach is convenient and concise, its downside is that stdout output too is collected in full in memory first, and *then* has to be output in order to print to the console (if needed), which negates the benefits of PowerShell's usual *streaming* of output: relaying output lines *as they're being received*; in addition to potentially wasting memory if stdout needn't be collected in memory as a whole, this can be undesired in long-running external programs where ongoing visual feedback is important; see the next approach for a solution.

**Combining in-memory capturing of stderr output with *streaming* stdout:**

This approach avoids the `.Where()` solution's collect-all-stdout-first behavior in favor of streaming stdout line as they're being received:

```bash
$stderr = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

# Merge the streams first, so that stderr too goes to the success stream, 
# then decide based on the type whether to pass the line through (stdout)
# or to collect them in list $stderr.
cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch 2>&1 | 
  % { if ($_ -is [string]) { $_ } else { $stderr.Add($_) } }
```

---

**Potential future improvement:**

[GitHub issue #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332) proposes extending the redirection syntax in order to allow collecting stderr lines in a *variable* much more simply:

```bash
 # As of v7.2.x: WISHFUL THINKING
 # Collect stderr lines in variable $stderr
 $stdout = cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch 2>variable:stderr
```