# Getting output powershell function for terraform

Tags: powershell, terraform

I'm using a powershell script to execute a terraform command, and when I have it inline with my code, I get terraform info printed to the host, which is what I want.

Once I wrapped the command in a function, I'm not getting the terraform output (only get the error response if there is one).

Is there a way to get the output to return from the function in real time (so I'm not sitting around wondering what is happening)?

EX:

```
Terraform init
```

vs

```
Function Example 
{
    PARAM($dirPath)
    cd $dirPath
    terraform init
}
Example -dirPath "C:\Test\"
```

Additionally, is there a way to actually capture if there is an error in the terraform response and halt the script? I've already set erroractionpreference = 'Stop' but that doesn't seem to capture the terraform error.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184827/powershell-capture-the-output-from-external-process-that-writes-to-stderr-in-a) be of help perhaps?

Comment: That does it! Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped a bit.

Comment: Add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, the comment as answer.

To capture output from an external application, you may need to redirect the **error** output stream to the **success** output stream in order to receive them both.
To do that, you can use the following in your fuction:

```
terraform init 2>&1
```

The `2>` redirects the error output stream (stderr) to the success stream (stdout) with `&1` and by doing so, you will merge both streams.

All of this is explained **MUCH** better than I can in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184827/powershell-capture-the-output-from-external-process-that-writes-to-stderr-in-a) by [manojlds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526535/manojlds) and especially [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)