# CMD pipe different form Powershell pipe?

Tags: powershell, cmd, pipe

I am trying to pipe Node.js output to preatty-pino

`node .\dist\GameNode.js | pino-pretty`

running this in the CMD I get my formated output but running it inside a powershell I get nothing.
I read that Powershell is using objects when piping, so I tried

`node .\dist\GameNode.js | Out-String -Stream | pino-pretty`

But this also does not work.

Why does it work inside CMD but not inside Powershell ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>Note: The specific `pino-pretty` problem described in the question is *not* resolved by the information below. Lukas (the OP) has filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty/issues/173).</sup>

It's surprising that you get *nothing*, but the **fundamental difference** is:

- **`cmd.exe`'s pipeline conducts *raw data***, i.e. *byte* streams (which a given program receiving the data may or may not *itself* interpret as *text*).
- **PowerShell's pipeline, when talking to *external programs*, conducts *only text*** (strings), which has two implications:

  - **On piping data *to* an external program, text must be *encoded***, which happens based on the character encoding stored in **[preference variable `$OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding)**.
  - **On receiving data *from* an external program, data must be *decoded***, which happens based on the character encoding stored in **`[Console]::OutputEncoding`**, which by default is the system's OEM code page, as reflected in `chcp`.

    - In ***Windows PowerShell*** and **[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.3.x***, this **decoding happens *invariably*, irrespective of whether the data is then further processed in PowerShell or passed on to *another* external program**.

      - In PowerShell (Core) **v7.4+**, however, ***raw byte data* now *is* passed *between external programs* and to `>` or `>>`**. Additionally, you can now use an array of bytes to send raw bytes to an external program - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).
    - The only *exception* is if external-program output is neither captured, sent on through the pipeline, nor redirected to a file: in that case, the data *prints straight to the console* (terminal), but only in a *local* console (when using PowerShell remoting to interact with a *remote* machine, decoding is again invariably involved).

      - This direct-to-display printing can sometimes *hide* encoding problems, because some programs, notably `python`, use full Unicode support *situationally* in that case; that is, the output may *print* fine, but when you try to *process it further*, encoding problems can surface.
      - A **simple way to force decoding** is to **enclose the call in `(...)`**; e.g.,
        `python -c "print('eé')"` *prints* fine, but
        `(python -c "print('eé'))"` surfaces an encoding problem; see the bottom section for more information

While **console applications traditionally use the active OEM code page** for character encoding and decoding, **Node.js always uses UTF-8**.

Therefore, in order for PowerShell to communicate properly with Node.js programs, you must (temporarily) set the following first:

```bash
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

If you want to ***fundamentally* switch to UTF-8**, either system-wide (which has far-reaching consequences) or only for PowerShell console windows, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

---

As an aside: an intermediate `Out-String -Stream` pipeline segment is never needed for relaying an external program's output - it is effectively (a costly) no-op, because streaming stdout output line by line is what PowerShell does by default. In other words: it is not surprising that it made no difference in your case.

---

#### Optional reading: Convenience function `Invoke-WithEncoding` and diagnostic function `Debug-NativeInOutput` for ad-hoc encoding needs / diagnosis:

If switching all PowerShell consoles to UTF-8 isn't an option and/or you need to deal with "rogue" programs that use a specific encoding other than UTF-8 or the active OEM code page, you can install:

- Function **`Invoke-WithEncoding`**, which **temporarily switches to a given encoding when invoking an external program**, directly from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/ef57aea441ea8bd43387a7d7edfc6c19) as follows (I can assure you that doing so is safe, but you should always check):

```bash
# Download and define advanced function Invoke-WithEncoding in the current session.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/ef57aea441ea8bd43387a7d7edfc6c19/raw/Invoke-WithEncoding.ps1 | iex
```

- Function **`Debug-NativeInOutput`**, which **helps diagnose encoding problems with external programs**, directly from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/eac1f18fbe0fc2798b214229b747e5dd) as follows (again, you should check first):

```bash
# Download and define advanced function Debug-NativeInOutput in the current session.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/eac1f18fbe0fc2798b214229b747e5dd/raw/Debug-NativeInOutput.ps1 | iex
```

---

Below are **example commands** that use a `python` command to print an accented character.

Like Node.js, Python's behavior is nonstandard, although it doesn't use UTF-8, but the system's active *ANSI*(!) code page (rather than the expected *OEM* code page).

That is, even if you switch your PowerShell consoles UTF-8, communication with Python scripts won't work properly by default, unless extra effort is made, which `Invoke-WithEncoding` can encapsulate for you:

<sup>Note: I'm using Python as an example here, to illustrate how the functions work. It *is* possible to make Python use UTF-8, namely by either setting environment variable `PYTHONUTF8` to `1` or - in v3.7+ - by passing parameter `-X utf8` (case-exactly).</sup>

---

**`Invoke-WithEncoding` example:**

```bash
# Outputs *already-decoded* output, so if the output *prints* fine, 
# then *decoding* worked fine too.
PS> Invoke-WithEncoding { python -c "print('eé')" } -Encoding Ansi -WindowsOnly
eé
```

- Note that `Invoke-WithEncoding` ensures that *actual decoding* to a .NET string happens before it outputs, so that encoding problems aren't accidentally masked by the *direct-to-display* output *seemingly* being correct on Windows (see below for more).
- `-WindowsOnly` is for cross-platform compatibility and ensures that the encoding is only applied on Windows in this case (on Unix, Python uses UTF-8).

---

**`Debug-NativeInOutput` example:**

With the PowerShell console at its default, using the system's OEM code page, you'll see the following output with the same Python command, calling from PowerShell (Core) 7.1:

```bash
PS> Debug-NativeInOutput { python -c "print('eé')" }
```

[image: Debug-NativeInOutput]

- Note the **`DecodedOutput` property**, showing the ***mis*-decoded result** based on interpreting Python's output as *OEM*- rather than as ANSI-encoded: `'eΘ'`. (The `Input*` properties are blank, because the command did not involve piping data *to* the Python script.)
- By contrast, with *direct-to-display* printing the output *prints* fine (because Python then - and only then - uses Unicode), which *hides* the problem, but as soon you want to *programmatically process* the output - capture in a variable, send to another command in the pipeline, redirect to a file - the encoding problem will surface.
- Like `Invoke-WithEncoding`, `Debug-NativeInOutput` supports an `-Encoding` parameter, so if you pass `-Encoding Ansi` to the call above, you'll see that Python's output is decoded properly.
- The output reflects the fact that, in PowerShell (Core), `$OutputEncoding` defaults to UTF-8, whereas in Windows PowerShell it defaults to ASCII(!). This mismatch with the actual encoding in effect in the console window is problematic, and [this comment on GitHub issue #14945](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14945#issuecomment-800503184) proposes a way to resolve this (for PowerShell (Core) only) in the future.