# On Windows, PowerShell misinterprets non-ASCII characters in mosquitto_sub output

Tags: windows, powershell, character-encoding, mosquitto, powershell-core

Note: This self-answered question describes a problem that is specific to using [Eclipse Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) on *Windows*, where it affects both *Windows PowerShell* and the cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition, however.

I use something like the following `mosquitto_pub` command to *publish* a message:

```
mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t tofol/test -m '{ \"label\": \"eé\" }'
```

<sup>Note: The extra `\`-escaping of the `"` characters, still required as of Powershell 7.1, *shouldn't be necessary*, but that is a separate problem - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).</sup>

*Receiving* that message via `mosquitto_sub` unexpectedly mangles the non-ASCII character `é`  and prints `Θ` instead:

```
PS> $msg = mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t tofol/test; $msg

{ "label": "eΘ" }  # !! Note the 'Θ' instead of 'é'
```

- Why does this happen?
- How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:

While the [`mosquitto_sub` man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html) makes no mention of *character encoding* as of this writing, it seems that ***on Windows* `mosquitto_sub` exhibits *nonstandard behavior* in that it uses the system's active *ANSI* code page** to encode its string output rather than the *OEM* code page that console applications are expected to use.<sup>[1]</sup>

There also appears to be no *option* that would allow you to *specify* what encoding to use.

PowerShell decodes output from external applications into *.NET strings*, based on the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which defaults to the *OEM* code page. Therefore, when it sees the ANSI byte representation of character `é`, `0xe9`, in the output, it interprets it as the OEM representation, where it represents character `Θ` (the assumption is that the active ANSI code page is Windows-1252, and the active OEM code page IBM437, as is the case in US-English systems, for instance).

You can verify this as follows:

```sh
# 0xe9 is "é" in the (Windows-1252) ANSI code page, and coincides with *Unicode* code point
# U+00E9; in the (IBM437) OEM code page, 0xe9 represents "Θ".
PS> $oemEnc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([int] (Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage OEMCP)); 
    $oemEnc.GetString([byte[]] 0xe9)

Θ   # Greek capital letter theta
```

Note that the decoding to *.NET strings* ([`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)) that invariably happens means that the characters are stored as *UTF-16 code units* in memory, essentially as `[uint16]` values underlying the [`System.Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char) instances that make up a .NET string. Such a code unit encodes a *Unicode character* either in full, or - for characters *outside* the so-called BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) - *half* of a Unicode character, as part of a so-called *surrogate pair*.

In the case at hand this means that the `Θ` character is stored as a *different* code point, namely a *Unicode* code point: `Θ` (*Greek capital letter theta*, [`U+0398`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/398)).

---

**Solution**:

**Note**: A simple way to solve the problem is to *activate system-wide support for UTF-8* (available in Windows 10), which sets *both* the ANSI and the OEM code page to `65001`, i.e. UTF-8. However, this feature is (a) still in *beta* as of this writing and (b) has far-reaching consequences - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for details.
However, it amounts to the most fundamental solution, as it also makes *cross-platform* Mosquitto use work properly (on Unix-like platforms, Mosquitto uses UTF-8).

**PowerShell must be instructed what character encoding to use** in this case, which can be done as follows:

```
PS> $msg = & { 
      # Save the original console output encoding...
      $prevEnc = [Console]::OutputEncoding
      # ... and (temporarily) set it to the active ANSI code page.
      # Note: In *Windows PowerShell* - only - [System.TextEncoding]::Default work as the RHS too.
      [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([int] (Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage ACP))

      # Now PowerShell will decode mosquitto_sub's output  correctly.
      mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t tofol/test

      # Restore the original encoding.
      [Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEnc
    }; $msg

{ "label": "eé" }  # OK
```

<sup>Note: The [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) cmdlet requires PowerShell version 5 or higher; in earlier version, either use `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.TextEncoding]::Default` or, if the code must *also* run in PowerShell (Core), `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([int] (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage ACP).ACP)`</sup>

---

**Helper function `Invoke-WithEncoding`** can encapsulate this process for you. You can install it directly [from a Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/ef57aea441ea8bd43387a7d7edfc6c19) as follows (I can assure you that doing so is safe, but you should always check):

```
# Download and define advanced function Invoke-WithEncoding in the current session.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/ef57aea441ea8bd43387a7d7edfc6c19/raw/Invoke-WithEncoding.ps1 | iex
```

The workaround then simplifies to:

```
PS> Invoke-WithEncoding -Encoding Ansi { mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t tofol/test }

{ "label": "eé" }  # OK
```

A similar function focused on *diagnostic* output is `Debug-NativeInOutput`, discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375).

---

As an aside:

While PowerShell isn't the problem here, it too can exhibit problematic character-encoding behavior.

**[GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233) proposes making PowerShell (Core) windows *default to UTF-8*** to minimize encoding problems with *most* modern command-line programs (it wouldn't help with `mosquitto_sub`, however), and [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14945#issuecomment-800503184) fleshes out the proposal.

---

<sup>[1] Note that Python too exhibits this nonstandard behavior, but it offers UTF-8 encoding as an opt-in, either by setting environment variable `PYTHONUTF8` to `1`, or via the v3.7+ CLI option `-X utf8` (must be specified case-exactly!).</sup>