# How does PowerShell display the output string resulting from invoking an external terminal application (nssm.exe)

Tags: windows, powershell

In PowerShell (5.1):

Calling an external command (in this case `nssm.exe get logstash-service Application`) the output  is displayed in PowerShell as I would have expected (ASCII-string "M:\logstash-7.1.1\bin\logstash.bat"):

```
PS C:\> M:\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe get logstash-service Application

M:\logstash-7.1.1\bin\logstash.bat
```

But the following command (which pipes the output into `Out-Default`) results in:

```
PS C:\> M:\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe get logstash-service Application | Out-Default

M : \ l o g s t a s h - 7 . 1 . 1 \ b i n \ l o g s t a s h . b a t
```

(*Please note all that "whitespace" separating all characters of the resulting output string*)

Also the following attempt to capture the output (as an ASCII string) into variable `$outCmd` results in :

```
PS C:\> $outCmd = M:\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe get logstash-service Application

PS C:\> $outCmd

M : \ l o g s t a s h - 7 . 1 . 1 \ b i n \ l o g s t a s h . b a t

 

PS C:\>
```

Again, please note the separating whitespace between the characters.

Why is there a difference in the output between the first and the latter 2 commands?

Where are the "spaces" (or other kinds of whitespace chars) coming from in the output of the latter 2 commands?

What exactly needs to be done in order to capture the output of that external command as ASCII string "M:\logstash-7.1.1\bin\logstash.bat" (i.e. without the strange spaces in between)?

If the issue is related to ENCODING, please specify what exactly needs to be done/changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the **problem is one of *character encoding***, and the problem often only **surfaces when an external program's output is either *captured in a variable*, *sent through the pipeline*, or *redirected to a file***.

Only in these cases does PowerShell get involved and *decodes* the output into .NET strings before any further processing.

This **decoding happens based on the encoding stored in the `[Console]::OutputEncoding` property**, so for programs that do not themselves respect this encoding for their output **you'll have to set this property to match the actual character encoding used**.

Your symptom implies that `nssm.exe` outputs UTF-16LE-encoded ("Unicode") strings<sup>[1]</sup>, so to capture them properly you'll have to do something like the following:

```sh
$orig = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode

# Store the output lines from nssm.exe in an array of strings.
$output = M:\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe get logstash-service Application

[Console]::OutputEncoding = $orig
```

---

The underlying problem is that **external programs are expected to use the current console's output code page** for their output encoding, which **defaults to the system's active legacy *OEM* code page**, as reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` (and reported by `chcp`), but **some do not**, in an attempt to:

- either: overcome the limitations of the legacy, single-byte OEM encodings in order to provide full Unicode support (as is the case here, although it is more common to do that with UTF-8 encoding, as the Node.js CLI, `node.exe` does, for instance)
- or: use the more widely used active *ANSI* legacy code page instead (as `python` does by default).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for additional information, which also links to two helper functions:
`Invoke-WithEncoding`, which wraps capturing output from an external program with a given encoding (see example below), and `Debug-NativeInOutput`, for diagnosing what encoding a given external program uses.

With function `Invoke-WithEncoding` from the linked answer defined, you could then call:

```sh
$output = Invoke-WithEncoding -Encoding Unicode { 
            M:\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe get logstash-service Application 
          }
```

---

<sup>[1] The ***apparent* spaces in the output are actually `NUL` characters** (code point `0x0`) that stem from the `0x0` high bytes of 8-bit-range UTF-16LE code units, which includes all ASCII characters and most of Windows-1252): Because PowerShell, based on the single-byte OEM code page stored in `[Console]::Encoding` (e.g., `437` on US-English systems), interprets each *byte* as a whole character, the `0x0` bytes of 2-byte (16-bit) Unicode code units (in the 8-bit range) are mistakenly retained as `NUL` characters, and in the console these characters *present like* spaces.</sup>