# Powershell SetEnvironmentVariable not setting the variables as expected

Tags: powershell, windows-10, environment-variables

I'm attempting to save some environment variables based on the output of the command "wsl --list" using Powershell, when I debug this code it seems to be flowing as expected however when I inspect my environment variables I'm unable to find the expected keys and values.

When I use the same SetEnvironmentVariable method with any other hardcoded value it seems to work. Write-Host on $distroName results in the expected string too so I'm honestly lost on this. Any help would be appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
$wslListOutput = wsl --list
((Get-ChildItem env:*).Name | Select-String -Pattern "(SINDAGAL_INIT_DISTRO_([a-zA-Z=])*)|SINDAGAL_DEFAULT_DISTRO")
foreach ($line in $wslListOutput)
{
  $lineIsEmpty = ("" -eq $line) -or ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line))
  $Introline = $line -eq "Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:"

  if($lineIsEmpty -or $Introline){ continue } 
  
  if($line -Match "(([a-zA-Z]*) ([(Default)])*)"){
     $distroName = ($line -split ' ',2)[0]    
     [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("SINDAGAL_DEFAULT_DISTRO",$distroName)
  } else{
     $distroName = $line.ToUpper()
     $variablePath = "Env:SINDAGAL_INIT_DISTRO_${distroName}"
     [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("SINDAGAL_INIT_DISTRO_${distroName}",$true)
  }
}

# Cannot see the variables which are supposed to be set in here at all
((Get-ChildItem env:*).Name)
```

my wsl --list output:

```
┖[~]> wsl --list
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Debian (Default)
Alpine
```

Comment: You probably want to use `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("SINDAGAL_DEFAULT_DISTRO",$distroName, "Machine")`. Without specifying the target, `SetEnvironmentVariable()` creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the **current process**

Comment: Please, add your `$wslListOutput` list to the question.

Comment: On my system, code jumps into `else` branch and sets `SINDAGAL_INIT_DISTRO_=true`, although `$distroName` is not empty (it is 'UBUNTU-20.04'). Strangely enough, when hardcoding `$distroName` using the same value, it works.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments guys!

Comment: @Theo I tried adding that third parameter in, even though it doesn't error its still not saving my variables unfortunately.

Comment: @iRon I've added my wsl --list output in the question as you asked!

Comment: @zett42 Thats exactly whats happening for me, good to know its not an issue specific for my machine, very curious what the bug might be now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

This is an encoding issue. Redirected output of `wsl` is UTF-16 LE encoded, which is not automatically recognized by PowerShell (as of PS 7.1.5). Instead it always interprets the output using the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which on Windows defaults to the given system's legacy OEM code page (e.g. 437 on US-English systems).

As UTF-16 is a two-byte encoding we typically end up with embedded `\0` characters (code points below 256, such as the ASCII character set). These cause the string to be clipped, when calling `SetEnvironmentVariable`, because the API expects null-terminated strings.

### Solution

Set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to match the output encoding of the process, before launching it and restore the original encoding afterwards.

```
$oldEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode  # on Windows: UTF-16 LE

$wslListOutput = wsl --list

[Console]::OutputEncoding = $oldEncoding
```

Another common output encoding used by some programs is `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/7571258) for more in-depth information and an `Invoke-WithEncoding` cmdlet, which automates the process of temporarily changing and restoring the encoding.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I solved it by using a mix of both of your approaches. Its a shame that this is an issue, I personally wouldn't be able to diagnose this and probably would end up giving the whole project up :)

Comment: I think your own answer here is the best duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/q/72411284/45375 (I've placed it first in the list). Note that the - unfortunately named - `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode` encoding represents UTF-16LE on _all_ platforms.