# Change graph output encoding in pipe (powershell)

Tags: powershell, terraform

I'm using terraform on windows, and would like to visualize the graphs using Graphviz. However, there is a difference between the encoding that is being output by Terraform vs what Graphviz expects. Ideally, I want to do the following:

```
terraform graph -draw-cycles |  dot -Tsvg > output.svg
```

That doesn't work, because the output that is being given by terraform is in the wrong encoding. The following sequence works, but uses an intermediate file:

```
terraform graph -draw-cycles > output.tmp 
Get-Content .\output.tmp | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii output2.tmp
dot -Tsvg output2.tmp > output.svg
rm output.tmp
rm output2.tmp
```

However, I would like to do this without intermediate files using piping. A statement such as

```
terraform graph -draw-cycles | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii -PassThru | dot -Tsvg > output.svg
```

doesn't work. The output from the terraform graph statement is text, and apparantly the Set-Content commandlet needs additional information (Path?):

```
Set-Content : The input object cannot be bound because it did not contain the information required to bind all mandatory parameters:  Path
At line:1 char:32
+ ... rm graph -draw-cycles | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii -PassThru | dot - ...
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (digraph {:PSObject) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectMissingMandatory,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Set-Content` needs a `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` to a file it can write content to

Comment: Have a look at `[Console]::OutputEncoding`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69605231/7571258).

Comment: @Theo so I guess I can't use Set-Content then for my purpose....

Comment: @zett42 Your reference put me on the right track, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After reading the article referred to by zett42, I saw a reference to [CMD pipe different form Powershell pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904779/cmd-pipe-different-form-powershell-pipe/66905220#66905220) in the comments.

The easiest solution for my specific case is simply executing the call with cmd:

```
cmd /c "terraform graph -draw-cycles | dot -Tsvg > output.svg"
```

Using the `Invoke-WithEncoding` would also work, but is a little more involved.