# Remove empty lines after simple Format-list command

Tags: powershell, format-list

Suppose I'm running:

```
some_command_here | fl foo*
```

and I'm getting:

```
a fool and his money are soon parted
foot in the door

snafoo


foo-bar
```

Now, I want to filter out the empty lines. How do I do this?

Comment: `some_command_here | Where { $_ -ne $null }`. Does this help?

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**

```bash
# Remove empty lines from the fl (Format-List) output
# (Collects all output in memory first.)
@(Get-Date | fl | oss) -ne ''

# Streaming alternative
Get-Item /, $PSHOME | fl | oss | ? { [bool] $_ }
```

- `Get-Date` and `Get-Item /, $PSHOME` are *sample* commands.
- `fl` is a built-in alias of the [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-List) cmdlet.
- `oss` is a built-in function that wraps [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-String) with the `-Stream` switch to produce line-by-line output.
- `?` is a built-in alias of the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Where-Object) cmdlet.

Read on for background information.

---

Note:

- The answer below, in line with the question, focuses on **filtering command output *via its for-display formatted string representations***, as produced by PowerShell's [formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview).

  - See the bottom section for a potentially *simpler solution* based on *external utilities* such as `grep` or `findstr.exe`, but on Windows there are *character-encoding pitfalls*.
- By contrast, if you're **looking to extract *data*** from command output, **rely on PowerShell's object-oriented nature and query / return *properties* of the input *objects***, using cmdlets such as [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object), [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), and [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object); e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Return those input objects whose .prop value starts with 'foo'
  [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 'foo' }, 
  [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 'other' }, 
  [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 'fool' } |
    Where-Object prop -like foo*
  ```

---

`Format-*` cmdlets such as `Format-List` (`fl`) output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375). In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*.

If you really want to filter the *for-display* output-formatting that [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) emits:

Note:

- What follows are PowerShell-native solutions; for the specific uses case at hand, piping to an *external utility* such as `grep` or `findstr.exe` is actually simpler, although there can be character-encoding issues - see the bottom section.

```bash
$sampleInput = [pscustomobject] @{ foo=1 },
               [pscustomobject] @{ other=2 },
               [pscustomobject] @{ fool=3 }

$sampleInput |
  Format-List -Property foo* | 
    Out-String -Stream |  # alternatively, use: oss
      Where-Object { '' -ne $_.Trim() }
```

<sup>Note: `Where-Object { [bool] $_ }` is enough to remove *empty* lines (but would keep *blank* lines, i.e. those composed of intra-line whitespace only), using PowerShell's to-Boolean coercing logic - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for details.</sup>

The above **lists only properties whose *name* starts with `foo`** (as `fl foo*` does in your question), along with their values, and **eliminates empty and blank lines from the *formatted output*** and therefore outputs:

```
foo : 1
fool : 3
```

Note:

- Since `Format-List`, as noted, produces formatting instructions, not text, [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) `-Stream` is needed to convert those instructions into a stream of text lines representing the rendering of these formatting instructions, i.e. the output you would normally see in the console.
- The [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) then eliminates empty or blank (all-whitespace) lines from the resulting output, by testing if the whitespace-trimmed (`.Trim()`) line at hand (`$_`) is non-equal to the empty string (`''`); note that you could omit the `'' -ne`  part, because PowerShell *implicitly* treats any non-empty string as `$true` in a Boolean context (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion rules)

---

If, by contrast, you want to **filter the formatted output produced by `Format-List` to those lines that contain substring `foo` *anywhere on the line***, i.e. irrespective of whether that substring is in the property name, its value, or even in a header line:

```bash
$sampleInput |
  Format-List |
    Out-String -Stream | 
      Select-String foo |
        ForEach-Object Line
```

Note:

- Unfortunately, `Out-String -Stream` is needed here too, because, as of PowerShell 7.2, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) does *not* automatically search the *for-display* representations of non-text / formatting-objects input - see [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726).
- To ease the pain somewhat, PowerShell ships with convenience function `oss`, which is short for `Out-String -Stream`.
- In PowerShell (Core) 7+, `Select-String` now supports the `-Raw` switch to pass only the matching lines (stringified input objects) through, without the default [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) wrapper; that is, you can then use `Select-String -Raw foo`, without also needing `ForEach-Object Line`.

---

**Searching through formatted for-display output using native utilities, such as `grep` and `findstr.exe`**:

You can take advantage of the fact that when PowerShell sends input to *external programs*, it essentially performs `Out-String -Stream` *implicitly*:

- PowerShell only "speaks text" when communicating with external programs, so it must send a *string* representation when piping (non-string) data to an external program. By default, it uses the same *for-display* representation you would see in the PowerShell console, sent *line by line*.
- It follows that extra work is needed if you want to send data that is suitable *for programmatic processing*: you must then use a  *structured* text format, such as JSON (via [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)) or CSV (via [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv))

In your case, the implication is that you can **simply pipe to a standard string-search utility such as `grep` on Unix-like platforms, and `findstr.exe` on Windows**:

```bash
# Windows
$sampleInput | Format-List | findstr foo

# Unix (macOS, Linux)
$sampleInput | Format-List | grep foo
```

Note: You don't strictly need a `Format-*` call; if the *default* formatting of your command output results in the desired representation, you can pipe *directly* for `grep` / `findstr.exe`.

***On Windows***, however, if your (formatted) command output comprises **non-ASCII-range characters, more work is needed** (usually *not* a concern on *Unix*-like platforms, where (BOM-less) UTF-8 is pretty much universally used these days):

- You'll have to set [the `$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding) to the character encoding that the target program expects, which in the case of `findstr.exe` is the system's
  legacy *OEM* code page, by default reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` (and in the output from `chcp.com`).

  ```bash
  $OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
  ```

Note that `[Console]::OutputEncoding` is also what PowerShell uses to decode output received *from* external programs, into .NET strings.

As a general aside: Given that certain modern programs, such as Node.js (`node.exe`), invariably use *UTF-8* encoding, irrespective of the active OEM code page - in an effort to overcome the limited character sets of the legacy Windows code pages - you may have to (temporarily) set *both* values in order to both *send* and *receive* text properly:

```bash
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

For more information on how PowerShell handles character encoding when communicating with external programs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375).

Comment: my take away from this answer was to strip blank lines use `Format-List | Out-String -Stream | Where-Object { $_ -ne ""}`

(i just wanted less gaps unless **i** put them there)