# How to set Select-String encoding to UTF-16?

Tags: powershell, unicode

I have a PowerShell script.
It executes exe file which produces UTF-16 output and I'm piping it into Select-String like this:

```
& "my.exe" | Select-String -Pattern "skipping non-regular file" -NotMatch -Encoding "utf-16"
```

But PowerShell reports, that the encoding is not supported.

Is there a workaround to fix this? Is UTF-16 really not supported?

Comment: The name for that encoding in .NET is `Unicode`, not `utf-16`.

Comment: Does the output start with a BOM?

Comment: Can you post a source code example as simply as possible?

Answer (score 1):

- **[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Encoding` parameter does *not* apply to *string* input from the pipeline**, as is the case with output from an *external program*.

  - Instead, it **only applies to *file* input** - namely to the *content* of files passed either via via the pipeline as the output from a `Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Item` call or via the `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` parameters. **`-Encoding` *generally* applies  only to the content of *files*, across all standard cmdlets.**
  - As an aside: As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) notes, the error message you saw stems from the fact that `utf-16` isn't a valid `-Encoding` argument in *Windows PowerShell*; (unfortunately), you must use the misnomer `Unicode` to refer to UTF-16LE.

    - Use `Get-Help Select-String -Parameter Encoding` to see the supported names or consult [the docs online](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string).
    - However, note that encoding names `utf-16` and `utf-16le` *do* work in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where `-Encoding` *additionally* accepts any name or code-page number from among all the available .NET encodings, as reported by `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings()`.
- Instead, **you must (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to UTF-16LE ("Unicode")** to get PowerShell to correctly decode the UTF-16LE output from your external program, as shown next.

```sh
$prev = [Console]::OutputEncoding # Save current value.

# Tell PowerShell to interpret external-program output as 
# UTF-16LE ("Unicode") encoded.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode

& "my.exe" |
  Select-String -Pattern "skipping non-regular file" -NotMatch

[Console]::OutputEncoding = $prev # Restore previous value.
```

See also:

- For more information on how PowerShell handles character encoding when communicating with external programs, including helper functions `Invoke-WithEncoding` and `Debug-NativeInOutput`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I came up with.  I'm not sure how to make it work.

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace myApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Byte[] byteOrderMark;
            byteOrderMark = Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble();
            //Console.OutputEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, true); 
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

```
$env:path += ';C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319'
csc Program.cs

# no output for either
.\Program | select-string Hello
.\Program | select-string Hello -encoding unicode


# no 'FF FE' BOM
.\program | Format-Hex


           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00  H.e.l.l.o. .W.o.
00000010   72 00 6C 00 64 00 21 00                          r.l.d.!.
```

If you want to bother searching for the nulls between each letter:

```
 .\program | select-string h`0e

H e l l o   W o r l d !
```

It still seems to me like using utf8 and the powershell ise is the best option, even with windows terminal being available.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell can search for the string. The search works across ASCII and UTF-16 log files.

Search any .log file in the current directory:

```
get-content "*.log" | Select-String -Pattern "Configuration completed successfully."
```