# Command Line Command Output in start-process from exe file

Tags: powershell, command-line, start-process, powershell-5.1

Here is the program. I am using dell command | configure. The command-line command is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\Command Configure\X86_64>cctk.exe" --wakeonlan
```

In Powershell you can navigate to the folder and run:

```
./cctk.exe --wakeonlan
```

I can pipe the above command into a variable and get the information I need. This requires my shell to cd into the folder accordingly and run accordingly.

```
$test = ./cctk.exe --wakeonlan
```

This will give you an output. However when you use start-process, you get no output as this is a command-line command. A cmd screen appears and runs the command. So, I added a -nonewwindow and -wait flags. The output now appears on the screen, but I can't seem to capture it.

```
$test = start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\Command Configure\X86_64\cctk.exe" -ArgumentList @("--wakeonlan") -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

At this point test is empty. I tried using the Out-File to capture the information as well. No success. The command outputs to the screen but nowhere else.

I also tried the cmd method where you pipe the information in using the /C flag.

```
$test = Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/C start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\Command Configure\X86_64\cctk.exe" "--wakeonlan"' -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

However, I have tried many variations of this command with no luck. Some say C:\Program is not recognized. Some just open command prompt. The above says --wakeonlan is an unknown command.

Any pointers would help greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to run this without the added complication of start-process.

Add to the path temporarily:

```
$env:path += ';C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\Command Configure\X86_64;'
cctk
```

Call operator:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\Command Configure\X86_64\cctk'
```

Backquote all spaces and parentheses:

```
C:\Program` Files` `(x86`)\Dell\Command` Configure\X86_64\cctk
```

Comment: This is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70100426/45375):

In short: Because your **executable path is *quoted*, direct invocation requires use of `&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), for *syntactic* reasons - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for details.

To **synchronously execute *console applications* or batch files and capture their output, call them *directly*** (`$output = c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `$output = & $exePath ...`), **do *not* use `Start-Process`** (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) for more information.

**If you do use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)**, which may be necessary in special situations, such as needing to run with a *different user identity*:

- The **only way to capture output is in *text files***, via the `-RedirectStandardOutput` / `-RedirectStandardError` parameters. Note that the character encoding of the output files is determined by the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`<sup>[1]</sup>, which reflects the current console output code page, which defaults to the system's active legacy *OEM* code page.
- By contrast, even with `-NoNewWindow -Wait`, *directly* capturing output with `$output = ...` does *not* work, because the launched process writes *directly to the console*, bypassing PowerShell's success output stream, which is the one variable assignments capture.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell uses the same encoding to decode output from external programs in *direct* invocations - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for details.</sup>