# How to echo JSON content to an exe file and then save the output to a file?

Tags: powershell, protocol-buffers

I am using a script in git bash, which performs few curl calls to HTTP endpoints expecting and producing protobuf.

The curl-output is piped to a custom proto2json.exe file and finally the result is saved to a JSON file:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR=$(dirname $0)
JSON2PROTO="$SCRIPT_DIR/json2proto.exe"
PROTO2JSON="$SCRIPT_DIR/proto2json.exe"

echo '{"key1":"value1","version":3}' | $JSON2PROTO -v 3 > request.dat

curl --insecure --data-binary @request.dat --output - https://localhost/protobuf | $PROTO2JSON -v 3 > response.json
```

The script works well and now I am trying to port it to Powershell:

```
$SCRIPT_DIR = Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath
$JSON2PROTO = "$SCRIPT_DIR/json2proto.exe"
$PROTO2JSON = "$SCRIPT_DIR/proto2json.exe"

@{
        key1        = value1;
        version     = 3;
} | ConvertTo-Json | &$JSON2PROTO -v 3 > request.dat
```

Unfortunately, when I compare the generated binary files in "git bash" and in Powershell, then I see that the latter file has additionaly zero bytes entered.

Is the [GitHub issue #1908](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908) related to my issue?

Comment: As an aside: I suggest placing a space between `&`, the call operator, and its operand (the command to call); this helps readability in general, but is also better for symmetry with the related dot-sourcing operator, `. `, which _requires_ a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're ultimately after this:

```
$SCRIPT_DIR = Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath
$JSON2PROTO = "$SCRIPT_DIR/json2proto.exe"
$PROTO2JSON = "$SCRIPT_DIR/proto2json.exe"

# Make sure that the output from your $JSON2PROTO executable is correctly decoded
# as UTF-8.
# You may want to restore the original encoding later.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()

# Capture the output lines from calling the $JSON2PROTO executable.
# Note: PowerShell captures a *single* output line as-is, and
#       *multiple* ones *as an array*.
[array] $output = 
  @{
        key1        = value1;
        version     = 3;
  } | ConvertTo-Json | & $JSON2PROTO -v 3

# Filter out empty lines to extract the one line of interest.
[string] $singleOutputLineOfInterest = $output -ne ''

# Write a BOM-less UTF-8 file with the given text as-is,
# without appending a newline.
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(
  "$PWD/request.dat",
  $singleOutputLineOfInterest
)
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- In PowerShell, **`>` is an effective alias of the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet, whose default output character encoding in Windows PowerShell is "Unicode" (UTF-16LE)** - which is what you saw - and, in PowerShell (Core) 7+, BOM-less UTF8. To control the character encoding, call `Out-File` or, for text input, [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) with the `-Encoding` parameter.

  - Note that you may also have to ensure that an external program's output is first properly *decoded*, which happens based on the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for more information.
  - Note that you can't avoid these decoding + re-encoding steps in PowerShell as of v7.2.4, because **the PowerShell pipeline currently cannot serve as a conduit for raw bytes**, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375), which also links to the GitHub issue you mention.
  - Finally, note that both `Out-File` and `Set-Content` by default append a *trailing, platform-native newline* to the output file. While `-NoNewLine` suppresses that, it also suppresses newlines *between* multiple input objects, so you may have to use the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator to manually join the inputs with newlines in the desired format, e.g. `` (1, 2) -join "`n" | Set-Content -NoNewLine out.txt ``
- **If, in Windows PowerShell, you want to create UTF-8 files *without a BOM*, you can't use a file-writing *cmdlet* and must instead use *.NET APIs* directly** (PowerShell (Core) 7+, by contrast, produces BOM-less UTF-8 files *by default*, consistently). .NET APIs do and always have created BOM-less UTF-8 files by default; e.g.:

  - [`[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.WriteAllLines) writes the elements of an array as lines to an output file, with each line *terminated with a platform-native newline*, i.e. CRLF (`0xD` `0xA`) on Windows, and LF (`0xA`) on Unix-like platforms.
  - [`[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.WriteAllText) writes a *single* (potentially multi-line) string *as-is* to an output file.
  - **Important**: Always pass *full paths* to file-related .NET APIs, because PowerShell's current location (directory) usually differs from .NET's.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extensive answer, Michael. And the newlines explanation makes sense... After seeing the complexity though, I will stick to my oneliner "git bash" script.

Comment: Glad to hear it, helped, @Alexander; my pleasure. Yeah, it's unfortunate that PowerShell still hasn't learned to play nice with external programs.