# Pipe into executable through .lnk file

Tags: powershell, pipe, stdin, shortcut-file

I have an executable at `C:\Very\Long\Path\StreamToClipboard.exe`
The file `C:\InPath\StreamToClipboard.lnk` points to that executable.
The directory `C:\InPath` is in my PATH variable, and `.lnk` is in my PATHEXT variable.

In regular cmd, I can execute any of these commands:
`echo Hello | C:\Very\Long\Path\StreamToClipboard.exe`
`echo Hello | C:\InPath\StreamToClipboard.lnk`
`echo Hello | StreamToClipboard.lnk`
`echo Hello | StreamToClipboard`
and the the executable is started, the text "Hello" is correctly piped into that process.

In PowerShell, I can execute `echo Hello | C:\Very\Long\Path\StreamToClipboard.exe` and it works too. But all of the other commands don't work:

```
Fehler beim Ausführen des Programms "StreamToClipboard.lnk": Die angegebene ausführbare Datei ist keine gültige
Anwendung für diese Betriebssystemplattform.In Zeile:1 Zeichen:12
+ echo foo | C:\InPath\StreamToClipboard.lnk
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ echo foo | C:\InPath\StreamToClipboard.lnk
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

(and respective paths)
Which roughly translates to `Error while executing "StreamToClipboard.lnk": The specified executable file is not a valid application for this operating system plattform`.

Note that `echo Hello | "C:\Very\Long\Path\StreamToClipboard.exe"` also does not work, with a different error message:

```
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:14
+ ... cho Hello | "C:\Very\Long\Path\StreamToClipboard.exe"
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Ausdrücke sind nur als erstes Element einer Pipeline zulässig.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Roughly translates to `Expressions are only valid as the first element in a pipeline`.

If I, instead of creating the .lnk file, copy the entire executable to `C:\InPath\StreamToClipboard.exe`, then these commands:
`echo Hello | C:\InPath\StreamToClipboard.exe`
`echo Hello | StreamToClipboard.exe`
`echo Hello | StreamToClipboard`
work fine.

How can I get PowerShell to accept `echo Hello | StreamToClipboard` (where it's an .lnk file), or at least `echo Hello | StreamToClipboard.lnk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Unlike `cmd.exe`, **PowerShell does *not* support invoking shortcut files (`.lnk`) like *console applications***; instead:

  - A *new* console window opens, *asynchronously*.
  - The process in the new console window does NOT receive stdin input (via the pipeline):

    - If a *command* is used - such as `echo hello`, using the built-in `echo` alias for PowerShell's (rarely needed) `Write-Output` cmdlet - the following *error* occurs, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell (Core) 7.2.4:

      - `Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline`
    - If an *expression* - such as `'hello'` - is used, no error occurs, but the input is effectively *ignored*.
  - In other words: **PowerShell considers `.lnk` files *documents*, not executables, and defers to Windows (GUI) shell for opening them**;<sup>[1]</sup> in effect, invoking a `.lnk` file is like passing it to [`Invoke-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Invoke-Item) or [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process); adding `-Wait` to the latter makes the invocation synchronous, but still runs in a separate window and doesn't support stdin input; attempting to use `-NoNewWindow` and/or 
    `-RedirectStandardInput` (to provide stdin input via a *file*) results in an *error*, similar to the one you saw:<sup>[2]</sup>

    - `This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

---

**Workarounds**:

- **Call the target `.exe` file *directly* in your pipeline**, which - if your path is *quoted* and/or contains variable references or expressions - requires use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

```
# & is required, because the executable path is quoted.
# Note: 'Hello' is the PowerShell-idiomatic equivalent of
#        echo Hello
'Hello' | & "C:\Very\Long\Path\StreamToClipboard.exe"
```

Note: For simplicity, you may choose to *always* use `&` when invoking external programs, but it is only *required* in the cases mentioned above, discussed in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375).

- **Invoke the shortcut (`.lnk`) file via `cmd /c`**:

```
'Hello' | cmd /c C:\InPath\StreamToClipboard.lnk
```

Note that, in both workarounds, **character encoding issues** may arise, given that data is being sent to an *external program*:

- The [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#outputencoding) controls what encoding is used to send data *to* an external program.
- The encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` determines how PowerShell decodes data received *from* external programs.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] Note that (temporarily) appending `";.LNK"` to the value of `$env:PATHEXT`, the environment variable that lists all filename extensions that belong to *executables*, does *not* help.</sup>

<sup>[2] The reason is that these parameters cause `Start-Process` to switch from the `ShellExecute` WinAPI function to `CreateProcess`, and the latter only works with actual executables.</sup>

Comment: Awesome! The workaround with `cmd /c` works nicely!