# Why does my string containing "é" character gets outputed as "Ú"?

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, uipath, windows-1252

Here's the situation :

- I have an UiPath process containing an Invoke Power Shell activity
- In the Invoke Power Shell activity (set as IsScript), here's my script `python '/path/to/my/script.py'`. The ouput is saved as string

When I run my "script.py" file in any Powershell from my computer, the output I get is "Cédric" but when I run the script through UiPath, the output I get is "CÚdric".
I understand that the issue is somehow related to the encoding.

After some researchs, I found out that running this Powershell command line `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.EncodingName`, I get different results :

- In my system Powershell : "Western Europe (Windows)"
- In UiPath Powershell : "Unicode (UTF-8)"

I found out that the HEX adress of "é" is E9 when using Windows-1252 encoding. But in CP850 encoding, E9 is "Ú". So I guess this is the encoding relation I'm looking for. THOUGH, I tried many things in UiPath (C#) and Powershell commands, but nothing did resolve my problem. (tried both changing encoding values or converting string into bytes to change encoding output)

And to anticipate some questions :

- No, I'll not use "Invoke Python Script" activity in UiPath as it's broken
- Yes, I need to use this Python script
- Yes, I could use a "replace("Ú","é")" on the string output BUT I don't wan't to do it dumbly for every special character that could come, even more when there's a logical reason behind it

TLDR : Basically, the issue is located when UiPath interprets the Powershell console running the Python script

I've been stuck on that for 3 days now, only to get 2% more precise on the project I work (which is completely fine other than that); so it's not worth the time I spend on it, but I need to know

Comment: Switch to UTF-8 everywhere in your script and shells, and you should have consistent results. Add a piece of code we can try, and help if you want more help. See [MRE]

The Python script first line shoud look like: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: You are using the wrong Font.  The font you are using doesn't contain the character you are using.

Comment: @jdweng: _Character-encoding mismatches_, such as described in this question, are unrelated to _fonts_. The font would only be a problem if a character didn't _render_ as such, using a _placeholder_ (`? `) that signals that the font doesn't include a glyph for the character's code point. Please consider no longer posting comments that conflate these two unrelated aspects, so as not to confuse others.

Comment: @mklement0 : Both characters are are 0xE9.  There is no way of telling the difference except the Font that is used.  If the source was a text file with UTF-8 Encoding, then the Font determines the way code is displayed.  There is a glyph in the font and doesn't display the question mark (displays wrong character).

Comment: @jdweng: There's only _one byte_ at issue here, with value `0xE9`. How PowerShell _translates this byte value into a .NET `[char]` instance (a UTF-16 code unit)_ depends on the value of `[Console]::OutputEncoding`.
Python outputs byte `0xE9` meaning it to be character `é`, due to using Windows-1252 encoding. PowerShell, _misinterprets_ this byte as referring to character `Ú`, because it decodes the byte as CP850.
It is purely this encoding mismatch, resulting in _different characters_, that causes the problem, which has nothing to with fonts.

Comment: @jdweng: To spell out the misinterpretation:  `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString([byte[]] 0xe9)` (-> `é`) vs. `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(850).GetString([byte[]] 0xe9)` (-> `Ú`)

Comment: @mklement0: That is only if you are using Window Encoding.  If you have UTF-8 and output data it will use the font of the app.

Comment: @jdweng: honestly, I don't even know how to interpret your comment. A given (Unicode) _character_ (as opposed to a _byte or byte sequence_ that must first be _interpreted as_ a character and can therefore be interpreted differently) always renders _the same_ (though possibly not as itself, if the font doesn't have a glyph for it). If you think that any of my arguments are incorrect, dispute them specifically - your comment doesn't do that.

Comment: @mklement0 : A character in Net/Core is a class object that can be one or two bytes along with a property indicating if the character is one or two bytes.  A string is an array of characters.  When transmitting (or reading files) characters/strings. you are sending bytes, not the class object.  The OP is starting with bytes (not char/string) and is using PS (not necessarily Net/Core).  So if OP is displaying bytes than encoding does not apply.   Suppose the OP opens the bytes in Notepad (using UTF-8) what will he see?  It will depend on the Font that is used.

Comment: @jdweng: [`System.Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char) is a value type, not a class, and its instance are unsigned 16-bit integer value that constitutes a UTF-16 code unit - a .NET character  isn't made up of two bytes, and it has no properties (let
alone one indicating that indicates a byte count, which would be meaningless)
Fonts render _characters_, not _bytes_.

Comment: @jdweng: An external process'  (or file's) _byte stream_ may or may not encode characters (text); here it does: it is the Windows-1252 encoding of the string `Cédric`.
For this byte stream to be retransformed into the original string, the _same_ encoding must be used to decode it, and because PowerShell uses a _different_ encoding, a _different string_ results.
That is the only problem here.

Comment: @jdweng: There is no way to display _bytes_ as such - you can either choose to show their _values_ or you can interpret them _as characters_, which is what text editors such as Notepad do.
Interpretation as characters requires choosing an encoding (based on a default or the presence of a BOM). 
For a given encoding, the  characters render the same, regardless of what font is used (leaving incidental variations in appearance aside).

Comment: @mklement0 : Microsoft has brainwashed you into thinking everything needs encoding.  I'm from the Unix world that know how to separate layers.  Yes when you are looking at this issue as 16 bit data where everything is unicode character it is encoding.  But when you look at it from the real world of bytes it is a Font issue.  If you sent byte data to a printer that is using one Font the character would look one way, then you change the Font on the printer and the character would look different.  The bytes do not change.

Comment: @mklement0 : Encoding was designed to save bytes by mapping 8 bit characters to 16 bit characters.  The ASCII character 0x80 to 0xFF are mapped differently depending on the encoding so you only need to represent unicode character with 8 bits, but you do not get every unicode character, just 64 of the characters with each type of encoding.

Comment: @jdweng: The discussion focused on Windows, but it applies to Unix as well. Summary: In modern OSs, it is solely the _character encoding_ that determines how raw byte sequences are interpreted as 
[_Unicode code points_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Codespace_and_Code_Points) (characters), and 
the choice of _font_ only determines _stylistic variations_ of those characters.
The only exceptions are _symbol fonts_, such as [Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings) on Windows, 
which redefine the meaning of code points in order to be able to render specialty symbols.

Comment: @jdweng: I can't make sense of your comments about encoding. Again: if you find fault with any of my arguments, you need to address them specifically. Also, please refrain from incendiary phrases such as "brainwashed" and ad-hominem arguments in general. I strongly encourage you to spend more time familiarizing yourself with the fundamentals before posting future comments - you're doing the community a real disservice.

Comment: @mklement0m : You are brainwashed my Microsoft.  I went to graduate school where most of the Professors were from Bell Labs.  There were Scientist not the simple programmers at Microsoft.  A console in Windows has a Font option.  And if you change the Font and open a UTF-8 encoded file the characters 0x80 to 0x FF will appear  different depending on the Font.  A German, Italian, French Font will each show different character for the same byte.  A byte is a byte and the Font determines how it appears.  There is no need for encoding except in the Microsoft World.

Comment: @jdweng: There is no such thing as a "German, Italian, French font". Encoding applies to _every_ platform: deciding
what _character_ a byte value or sequence represents can only be done on the basis of a _character encoding_  (aka _codeset_, _charmap_).
Try it for yourself: Run `'hü' | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 test.txt; notepad test.txt` and then
change to any other (non-symbol) font - you'll see differences in _styling_, but the characters will remain the same.
What schooling you had and who your professors were is irrelevant. Stop the ad-hominem arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>As for [`[System.Text.Encoding]::Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding.Default): That you're seeing UTF-8 as the value in UiPath implies that it is using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (`pwsh.exe`), the modern, install-on-demand, cross-platform edition built on .NET 5+, whereas *Windows PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`), the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition is built on .NET Framework.</sup>

- **PowerShell honors the system's active legacy *OEM* code page by default** when interpreting **output from *external programs*** (such as Python scripts),<sup>[1]</sup>  e.g. [`850`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), as reported by `chcp`, and as reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` from inside PowerShell.

  - That is, PowerShell interprets the *byte stream* received from external programs as text encoded according to `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, and decodes it that way, resulting in a *Unicode* in-memory string representation, given that PowerShell is built on .NET whose strings are composed of UTF-16 Unicode code units (`[char]`). If `[Console]::OutputEncoding` doesn't match the *actual* encoding that the external program uses, *misinterpreted text* can be the result, as in your case.<sup>[2]</sup>

    - **Note**: This interpretation only comes into play when PowerShell either *captures* or *redirects* output from an external program. Otherwise, the output prints directly to the console *and the problem may not surface there*. For example, running `python script.py` results in `Cédric` printing *to the console*, but `python script.py | Write-Output` - due to use of a pipeline - involves interpretation by PowerShell, and the encoding mismatch would result in `CÚdric`
  - A **UTF-8 opt-in** is available:

    - Execute the following in PowerShell, *before* calling the Python script (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for background information):

      ```
      $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
      ```
- **Python, by contrast, defaults to the system's active legacy *ANSI* code page** (e.g. [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)).<sup>[3]</sup>

  - A **UTF-8 opt-in** is available, either:

    - By defining environment variable `PYTHONUTF8` with value `1`: *Before* calling your Python script, execute `$env:PYTHONUTF8=1` in PowerShell.
    - Or, in Python 3.7+, with explicit `python` CLI calls, by using the `-X utf8` option (case matters).

Note:

- Given the above - assuming that your Python script only ever outputs characters that are part of the Windows-1252 code page - the alternative is to leave Python at its defaults and (temporarily) set the console encoding to Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8:

  ```
  $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)
  ```

---

There is an **option to NOT require this configuration**, by **configuring Windows to use UTF-8 *system-wide***, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375), which sets *both* the active OEM and the active ANSI code page to `65001`, i.e. UTF-8.

- **Caveat**: This feature - still in beta as of Windows 11 22H2 - has **far-reaching consequences**:

  - It causes *preexisting, BOM-less files* encoded based on the *culture-specific* ANSI code page (e.g. Windows-1252) to be *misinterpreted by default* by Windows PowerShell, Python, and generally all non-Unicode Windows applications.
  - Note that .NET applications, including [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (but *not* Windows PowerShell),<sup>[1]</sup> - have the *inverse* problem that they must deal with *irrespective of this setting*: Because they assume that a BOM-less file is *UTF-8*-encoded, they must specify the culture-specific legacy ANSI code page explicitly when reading such files.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell-*native* commands and scripts, which run in-process, consistently communicate text via in-memory *Unicode* strings, due to using .NET strings, so no encoding problems can arise.

When it comes to reading *files*, *Windows PowerShell* defaults to the *ANSI* code page when reading source code and text files with `Get-Content`, whereas [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now - commendably - consistently defaults to UTF-8, also with respect to what encoding is used to *write* files - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for more information.</sup>

<sup>[2] Specifically, Python outputs byte `0xE9` meaning it to be character `é`, due to using Windows-1252 encoding. PowerShell, *misinterprets* this byte as referring to character `Ú`, because it decodes the byte as CP850, as reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`.  Compare `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString([byte[]] 0xE9)` (-> `é`, whose *Unicode* code point is `0xE9` too, because Unicode is mostly a *superset* of Windows-1252) to `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(850).GetString([byte[]] 0xE9)` (-> `Ú`, whose *Unicode* code point is `0xDA`)</sup>

<sup>[3] This applies when its stdout / stderr streams are connected to something *other than a console*, such when their output is captured by PowerShell.</sup>