# Integration for wix.com store api | diacritics problem

Tags: json, powershell, character-encoding, invoke-webrequest

annoying problem, maybe you can help me. Trying to pass data into "new product" on wix.com via API), but some of the products contains local signs. After invoke-webrequest is successfully processed (part of code below) on the server end I'm obtaining converted data without diacritics

Trying to enforce charset utf-8, and in $body I'm obtaining proper result,

```
$headers  = @{
     "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
     "Authorization" = "$auth"
     "charset"       = "UTF-8"
            }
[...]
$obj = @{
    "product" = @{
                "name"        = [string]($product.name)
               }
[...]

$body = $obj | convertto-json -depth 3;
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $url  -method POST -body $body
```

but on server all diacritics are gone. I believe there should be some possibility to change it, but seems that required some changes on server end. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Any help appreciated.
Thanks a lot for all answers.

Comment: Is this a font issue?  Are you trying to access data from a server that uses a different default language?

Comment: @jdweng, please don't comment on questions about character-encoding problems if you cannot tell the difference between a character encoding and a font (as explained in the comments exchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76227623/45375)). You'll only cause confusion.

Comment: @mklement0 : What happens if you are connecting to a computer that uses a different default language setting?  UTF-8 encoding will use the font on local machine and not the remote machine.  The title to the posting says OP is having a diacritics issue which means the wrong font is being used.

Comment: @jdweng, I invite you to read the information in the answer - which solved the problem - and then re-evaluate whether your comments are a meaningful contribution to this post.

Comment: @mklement0 : The issue is do to the character 0x80-0xFF being changed which can be do to Font or Encoding.  Why did Microsoft use ISO-8859-1 as the default instead of UTF-8.  This is a bug especially when the Content is JSON.  What is worse is there is no way of finding the bug unless you look at the library Source Code.  Using GZIP would also solve issue or sending a Base64string.  HTML has special characters that must be escaped. when using text in the body.  If Json uses UTF-8 as default why when OP uses charset UTF-8 does the characters change?

Comment: @jdweng, let me plead again: Please stop conflating fonts (which determine the appearance of already-known characters) and character encodings (which determine how _raw bytes_, as used in persisted storage and cross-process / network communication, are _interpreted as_ characters).
PowerShell historically used ISO-8859-1, based on a now obsolete version of the _HTML_ RFC.
Yes, it should never have used that encoding with _JSON_. Fortunately, v7.4+ now consistently uses UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Omit the `"charset"` entry from your `$headers` hashtable:

  - Media type `application/json` uses UTF-8 *by default*.
  - Aside from that, the `charset` attribute is meant to be a part of the `Content-Type` entry, not a separate one (e.g., `'Content-Type' = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'`)
- To **ensure that UTF-8 is used in the request body** in *Windows PowerShell* and PowerShell (Core) versions *up to v7.3.x*, explicitly obtain the UTF-8 encoding of the JSON string to post, via [`System.Text.UTF8Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.UTF8Encoding), and pass the result - a `[byte[]]` array - to the `-Body` parameter of [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) instead:

```bash
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $url -Method POST -Body (
  [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new().GetBytes($body)
)
```

---

###### Background information:

- In ***Windows PowerShell*** and in **[PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.3.x***:

  - These versions use [**ISO-8859-1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) as the **default character encoding** (v7.0 - v7.3.x selectively default to UTF-8, but only in responses, and only for media type `application/json`); ISO-8859-1 is largely identical to [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (the most common "ANSI" encoding), except that it is missing the latter's characters in the 0x80 - 0x9F code-point range, which notably includes the `€` symbol.
  - To **post UTF-8** instead, you have **two options**:

    - Only if you're not also using a `-Header` argument: **Use a `-ContentType` argument and append a `charset` attribute**; e.g. `-ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

      - This makes PowerShell *automatically* encode a `[string]`-typed `-Body` argument based on the specified encoding.
      - Note that up to v7.3.x the equivalent use of a `Content-Type` entry in a hashtable passed to the `-Header` argument was *not* honored; this is fixed in v7.4+
    - Alternatively, **manually create a `[byte[]]` array that contains the bytes that make up the UTF-8 encoding of your JSON string and pass it to `-Body`**, as shown at the top.
  - Note that with **`GET` requests**, you **may also have to prevent misinterpretation of *responses***; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034595/45375).
- In PowerShell (Core) **v7.4+**, *no* extra effort is needed **[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)** is now fortunately the **consistent default** in both [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod).

---

Comment: thank you so much, that solved all my issues. Really appreciate your help