# How to handle Unicode in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, unicode

I was trying to print info of a video in Youtube using yt-dlp and want to do stuff with it in PowerShell

Command:

```
yt-dlp.exe --print "{'domain': '%(webpage_url_domain)s', 'uploader': '%(uploader_id)s', 'status': '%(live_status)s', 'title': '%(title)s'}" https://www.youtube.com/live/nxbSLFv2JAs --ignore-no-formats-error
```

Output:

```
{'domain': 'youtube.com', 'uploader': '@AiraniIofifteen', 'status': 'was_live', 
'title': '【 Minecraft 】イオそらとえーちゃん仲良く大作戦【 iofi / hololive 】'}
```

but when i want to convert it using ConvertFrom-Json the Japanese characters and those【】gone.

Command:

```
yt-dlp.exe --print "{'domain': '%(webpage_url_domain)s', 'uploader': '%(uploader_id)s', 'status': '%(live_status)s', 'title': '%(title)s'}" https://www.youtube.com/live/nxbSLFv2JAs --ignore-no-formats-error | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Output:

```
domain      uploader         status   title
------      --------         ------   -----
youtube.com @AiraniIofifteen was_live  Minecraft  iofi / hololive
```

Because when it's fine when i don't use ConvertFrom-Json i don't think it's yt-dlp problem.
I also tried using some alternative way to do it and it doesn't seem to meet bright light.

Then I found out that do this (put previous command inside parenthesis)

```
(yt-dlp.exe --print "{'domain': '%(webpage_url_domain)s', 'uploader': '%(uploader_id)s', 'status': '%(live_status)s', 'title': '%(title)s'}" https://www.youtube.com/live/nxbSLFv2JAs --ignore-no-formats-error)
```

Already throw Japanese characters and the【】

Output:

```
{'domain': 'youtube.com', 'uploader': '@AiraniIofifteen', 'status': 'was_live',
'title': ' Minecraft  iofi / hololive '}
```

I have searched many solution regarding this matter but nothing solved this problem.

Stuff like chcp, $OutputEncoding, [System.Console]::OutputEncoding, [System.Console]::InputEncoding, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8. Didn't solve my problem. Or maybe because i don't really understand these things so i can't solve my problem.

I almost certain this question is a duplicate question, but the thing is I am not familiar with this stuff and so i don't know what to search to solve this specific problem.

Few stuff I've tried:

```
$OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
```

```
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = (new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false)
```

I also tried some other solution but i don't include it here because almost no way those solution will fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

In the yt-dlp side, I changed the title format to json and remove the single quotes.

```
'title': %(title)j
```

Command:

```
yt-dlp.exe --print "{'domain': '%(webpage_url_domain)s', 'uploader': '%(uploader_id)s', 'status': '%(live_status)s', 'title': %(title)j}" https://www.youtube.com/live/nxbSLFv2JAs --ignore-no-formats-error | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Output:

```
domain      uploader         status   title
------      --------         ------   -----
youtube.com @AiraniIofifteen was_live 【 Minecraft 】イオそらとえーちゃん仲良く大作戦【 iofi / hololive 】
```

But I think the question is still unanswered. Why if I pass `%(title)s` (string with Japanese characters and something like【】) to anything in PowerShell it doesn't handle this properly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer either, but sheds some more light on the situation:

It is `yt-dlp.exe` itself that is the problem, which is why [configuring PowerShell to use UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) doesn't help (calling from `cmd.exe` after running `chcp 65001` there doesn't help either):

- When printing output *to the console*, `yt-dlp.exe` *does* print non-ASCII-range Unicode characters such as `イ`
- When `yt-dlp.exe`'s output is *redirected* (such as to `ConvertFrom-Json` via a pipeline), seemingly all such characters are simply *removed*.

  - The [docs](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#output-template) describe Unicode-related options such as `+`, but I couldn't get them to work, at least in version 2023.03.04.

Because your `--print` argument happens to be JSON, using format type `j`  provides an effective solution, because the resulting JSON representation of the title uses Unicode *escape sequences* such as `\u3010` to represent non-ASCII-range Unicode characters, which means that the string is composed of ASCII-range characters only, which bypasses the original problem.