# How does one get the output from |Write-SqlTableData

Tags: powershell, variables, output, return-code

I'm using

```
## Import CSV into SQL
$CsvData = Import-Csv $CsvPath -Delimiter $CsvDelimiter 

$CsvData | Write-SqlTableData `
  -ServerInstance $ServerName `
  -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
  -SchemaName $TableSchema `
  -TableName $TableName `
  -Force  `
  -ConnectionTimeout(0) `
  -OutVariable $Out `
  -iv $Info
```

I'm trying to get the error message and or the return codes into a variable.
None of usual ways seem to work .

All of the output variables specified above - `$out` and `$info` - seem to always be empty.

Comment: Please check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also format your post please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: If you want the output stored in `$out` then you need to call `Write-SqlTableData ... -OutVariable out` - only specify the variable _name_, don't include `$`

Comment: What usual ways have you tried?

Comment: @Dennis, it isn't obvious, because it is scrolled out of view, but the - flawed - attempts were `-OutVariable  $out` and `-iv $info`. Mathias' comment provides the fix, which my answer builds on and complements with an explanation and background information.

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer:

The **self-chosen variable** you designate as the target of one of the  **common `-*Variable` parameters**, such as the [common `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable), [`-ErrorVariable` (`-ev`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-errorvariable), and [`-InformationVariable` (`-iv`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-informationvariable), **must be specified *by name only*, i.e. *without the `$` prefix***:

Therefore, in order to **capture success output in variable `$out`**, use **`-OutVariable out`**, not `-OutVariable` <del>`$out`</del>.

Analogously, use `-iv info` (`-InformationVariable info`), not `-iv` <del>`$info`</del>, to capture the information-stream output.

To capture (non-terminating) errors in, say, variable `$err`, use `-ErrorVariable err`
(or `-ev err`).

---

What `-OutVariable $out`, for instance, does is to use the *value* of variable `$out` as the name of the target variable, and if `$out` isn't defined, the reference evaluates to `$null`, which is the same as *not* specifying a target variable for `-OutVariable`, i.e. the parameter has *no effect* - which is what you saw.

Note that PowerShell has no concept of *return codes*; PowerShell commands produce *output* via its system of [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).

Additionally, there is an abstract success indicator in the form of the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1), which contains `$false` if at least one error occurred in the most recently executed command, and `$true` otherwise.

Error *details* must be gleaned from the error records (objects) emitted via the error output stream (whose number is `2`), and are also logged session-wide in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error).

---

##### Optional reading: How to capture output from commands that don't support common parameters:

- What the common `-*Variable` parameters do is to capture a given [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams)'s content in a self-chosen variable *without interfering with that output stream*; that is, the output stream's content is still *passed through*, and the target variable *also* captures it, for later use.
- However, use of common parameters is only an option if the command is either a cmdlet, or a (cmdlet-like) [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) function or script.

---

**For other commands *except external (native) programs***, you can wrap the call in a [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) call and use the latter's common parameters; e.g.:

```bash
# Define a simple (non-advanced) function that emits both success 
# and error output.
function SimpleFunc {
  'hi!'             # same as: Write-Output 'hi!'
  Write-Error 'err' # emit a non-terminating error
}

# Wrap the call in Invoke-Command and use the latter's common parameters.
# The output streams are passed through, and the success-output / error stream
# content is recorded in $out / $err
Invoke-Command -OutVariable out -ErrorVariable err { SimpleFunc }
```

Self-chosen variable `$out` now contains `'hi!'` and self-chosen variable `$err` contains an error record with message `'err'`.

---

**For *external (native) programs***, there is only a *suboptimal* solution:

- Unless the output streams of external programs - stdout and stderr -  are *explicitly redirected or captured*, PowerShell passes them straight through to the host (terminal). Therefore, the `Invoke-Command` solution above wouldn't capture them.

  - Arguably, however, the use of `-OutVariable` should *implicitly* act like the request to capture output from external programs too; see [GitHub issue #5758](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5758) for a discussion.
- You can force this capturing to happen simply by piping the external-program call to `Write-Output` (which effectively just *relays* the output lines), but only *stdout* output is by default passed through the pipeline.

  - Note that this may surface *character-encoding issues* that wouldn't necessarily surface in direct-to-host output: capturing involves decoding the output streams based on `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which must match the actual encoding used by the external program - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for background information.
- In order to also capture *stderr* output, you must [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) it into the success stream, using `2>&1`, but this invariably means that you can only capture the *combination* of the stdout and stderr streams, in a *single* variable, passed to `-OutVariable`

  - However, because PowerShell records stderr lines wrapped in [`[ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances, you can separate the stream output *afterwards*, using the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where), as shown below.

```bash
# Capture the *combined* stdout and stderr output in $outAndErr
Invoke-Command -OutVariable outAndErr { 
  cmd /c 'ver & dir nosuch' 2>&1 | Write-Output
}

# Now split the captured lines into those that come from stdout vs. stderr.
$out, $err = $outAndErr.Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split')
```

Note:

- If you don't need to also pass the output streams *through*, you can capture the output streams directly, as follows:

  ```bash
  $out, $err = (
    cmd /c 'ver & dir nosuch' 2>&1
  ).Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split')
  ```
- Possibly providing a mechanism analogous to `-OutVariable` for external-program calls has been suggested in [GitHub issue #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332), with syntax such as `2>variable:err`