# NativeCommandError while trying to combine output streams

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, stdout, stderr

Doing a Start-Transcript to capture logs from a node program. After starting the transcript the following command is entered:

```
PS > node . 2>&1
```

The above program outputs everything to console. After running the program, I ended it and stopped the transcript. Now I inspect the transcript to find specific application logs; I don't find them, and instead I find the below error:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ node . 2>&1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (2023-07-11T10:5...nabled":false}}:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `node` probably uses stderr to output certain messages - PowerShell then wraps them in ErrorRecord instances (because they're coming from the error stream) and you see this annoying output

Comment: Windows you command is appending the error output (2) to the standard output.  In power shell there are other types of outputs beside error and standard.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-output?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Call the `.ToString()` method on each output object to **ensure string-only output** (`%`, the built-in alias of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) is used for brevity):

```bash
node . 2>&1 | % ToString
```

**Caveat**:

- Capturing output from external programs or piping it to another command invariably subjects it to *decoding into .NET strings*, which can reveal a mismatch between the actual character encoding a given program uses and the one PowerShell uses for decoding, as reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which itself defaults to the console's active code page.

  - Thus, you may have to (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the actual encoding to ensure correct interpretation.
  - Indeed, given that `node` invariably produces UTF-8-encoded output, you'll need to (temporarily) set
    `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()` if your output comprises non-ASCII characters  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for details.

---

###### Background information

By using PowerShell's `2>&1` [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), a single stream of objects containing the merged stdout and stderr lines of the external program is sent to the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).

While the objects representing *stdout* lines are *strings*, those representing ***stderr* lines are [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances**.

In *Windows PowerShell*, these `[ErrorRecord]` instances render *like PowerShell errors*, which is what you saw. This is unfortunate, because stderr output *may or may not* represent actual *errors*, given that stderr is more generally used for anything that *isn't data*, such as status information.

Fortunately, this display problem has been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).<sup>[1]</sup>

As an aside: That PowerShell uses distinct data types for stdout vs. stderr lines actually offers an *advantage*: If you *capture* the resulting objects, you can determine each object's stream of origin via its *data type* (`-is [string]` vs. `-is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`)

See also:

- For a comprehensive discussion of redirecting output from external programs in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288514/45375).

---

<sup>[1] In the context of PowerShell [*remoting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote), however, `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` still render as if they were errors, though in v7+ in a much subtler form: their text prints in red as-is, without the extra information and multi-line representation seen in Windows PowerShell.</sup>