# In PowerShell, how can I get stdout and stderr from a native command interleave correctly when redirecting stderr to stdout?

Tags: powershell

Given a native command `output(.exe)` that writes output to `stdout` and/or `stderr` in the order specified on the command-line.

PowerShell 7.2 on macOS:

```
PS> ./output -o 1 -e 2 -o 3
1
2
3
PS> ./output -o 1 -e 2 -o 3 2>&1
1
3
2
```

Compare with Zsh on macOS:

```
% ./output -o 1 -e 2 -o 3
1
2
3
% ./output -o 1 -e 2 -o 3 2>&1
1
2
3
```

Windows PowerShell 5.1 (`stderr` is formatted differently when it's redirected, but other than that, order is the same as PowerShell 7.2 on macOS):

```
PS> .\output.exe -o 1 -e 2 -o 3
1
2
3
PS> .\output.exe -o 1 -e 2 -o 3 2>&1
1
3
./output.exe : 2
At line:1 char:1
+ ./output.exe -o 1 -e 2 -o 3 2>&1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (2:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Windows Command Processor (`cmd.exe`):

```
C:\> .\output.exe -o 1 -e 2 -o 3
1
2
3
C:\> .\output.exe -o 1 -e 2 -o 3 2>&1
1
2
3
```

What causes this behaviour in (Windows) PowerShell, and is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: You are taking error output and appending to standard output.  See following for PS output types : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-output?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng The documentation you linked to does not mention redirection. You use the term 'appending' in your comment, but according to [about Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) only `>>` _appends_, whereas `>&1` _redirects_.

Comment: Works for me:  `findstr hi foo 2>&1 >$null` (no output, foo doesn't exist)

Comment: @js2010, the question is about output _ordering_, not suppression; that is, when PowerShell outputs the combined streams after redirecting stderr into the success output stream with `2>&1`, the output sequence typically doesn't match the original output sequence. The examples show that the original output sequence stdout line, stderr line, stdout line turns into stdout line, stdout line, stderr line on the PowerShell side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- You'e seeing the unfortunate consequence of a **design trade-off** in PowerShell, discussed in detail in [GitHub issue #5424](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5424).
- As a result of the design choices summarized below, when merging an *external program*'s stderr output into PowerShell's success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) with `2>&1`,  ***the original output ordering cannot be guaranteed***.
- **Workaround**: Use the ***native shell's* redirection features**, which *do* guarantee output ordering (see bottom section for additional information):

  - Unix-like platforms:

    ```
    /bin/sh -c './output -o 1 -e 2 -o 3 2>&1'
    ```
  - Windows:

    ```
    cmd /c '.\output -o 1 -e 2 -o 3 2>&1'
    ```

---

###### Summary of PowerShell's behavior:

When PowerShell redirects an external program's *stderr* stream - which maps onto PowerShell's loosely analogous *error (output) stream* (`2`) into its *success (output) stream* (`1`, PowerShell's analog to *stdout*) via a [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `2>&1` or `*>&1` (the two are equivalent only for *external* programs), it **still *captures* the external program's output streams *separately***, before sending them to the same output stream.

This allows it to send the respective stream's output as *objects with distinct (.NET) data types* to the success output stream (to the pipeline):

- *Stdout* lines are sent as *strings* ([`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)).

  - Note that, up to at least v7.3, PowerShell *invariably* parses an external program's output *as text*,<sup>[1]</sup> i.e. it parses it into .NET strings representing the *lines* of output based on the character encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding]`, which on Windows reflects the current console's output *code page*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for more information.
- *Stderr* lines are sent as strings *wrapped in [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances*, i.e. wrapped in the same type PowerShell uses to represent *its own* errors.

The potential **advantage** of this approach is:

- You can capture stderr lines *in memory* (which as of v7.3.x isn't otherwise possible; you can only send them to a *file*).

  - However, [GitHub issue #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332) proposes introducing syntax that would allow capturing stderr output *selectively* in *variables* via a redirection such as `2>variable:stdErrOutput` (to capture in variable `$stdErrOutput`)
- You can later separate stdout-originating lines from stderr-originating ones by their *data type*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288514/45375) for details and sample code.

The **cost** of capturing the streams *separately*, via separate (system) *pipes*, *before combining them* is that their **relative output ordering cannot be guaranteed** (which appears to be an inherent limitation of such pipes).

This is **problematic** in lengthy program output, where **you generally do want to see stderr output *in context***, namely right next to stdout output that was emitted just before.

---

###### Workaround via the native shells:

Since the **platform-native shells** (`/bin/sh` on Unix-like platforms, `cmd.exe`) ***do* guarantee ordering**, namely by *merging the streams at the source* - resulting in a single, unified output stream of *bytes*, calling *them*, using *their* (analogous) redirection features solves the problem (see top section), at the **expense** of:

- Being able to tell which lines came from which stream.
- The overhead of an extra child process.
- Needing to know the native shell's syntax rules, which differ from PowerShell's.
- Making *cross-platform* solutions difficult, due to differing path separators (`/` vs. `\`) and quoting syntax; applied to your call:

  ```
  $shell = & ('/bin/sh', 'cmd')[$env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT']
  $opt = ('-c', '/c')[$env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT']
  $pathSep = ('/', '\')[$env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT']
  $cmdLine = '.{0}output -o 1 -e 2 -o 3 2>&1' -f $pathSep
  & $shell $opt $cmdLine
  ```
- On a related note, needing to use *string interpolation* to embed PowerShell variables and expressions in the command line passed to the native shell, using an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)

  - This in turn can necessitate use of *embedded quoting*, which up to PowerShell 7.2.x is broken with respect to embedded *double*-quoting (`"..."`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)
  - With `cmd.exe` only (Windows), you can often - but not always - mitigate this problem by passing the parts of the command line as *individual arguments*, making sure that `2>&1` and `cmd.exe` metacharacters in general are *individually quoted*; e.g.

    ```
    cmd /c echo $HOME '&' dir /b nosuch '2>&1'
    ```

---

<sup>[1] *Preview* versions of PowerShell (Core) v7.4 have an *experimental* feature named [`PSNativeCommandPreserveBytePipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features#psnativecommandpreservebytepipe) that treats `>` and `|` when applied to *external (native) programs* as *raw byte conduits*, i.e. it bypasses the usual string-decoding and re-encoding cycle in favor of passing the raw data through.

(Note that, as with any experimental feature, it isn't *guaranteed* to become a stable feature.) However, the *raw-bytes behavior by design does *not* apply when using a stderr redirection*.</sup>

Comment: Great in-depth answer, thanks! With this knowledge I was able to make a decision: I want to be able to distinguish between `stdout` and `stderr` so I will give up trying to get them in order. Should order be more important at some point in the future, then I now know what price I'll have to pay to get that.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MichielvanOosterhout; that's a good summary.