# Show result of this cmdlet: Unlock-ADAccount

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So basic a question but I cannot find an elegant, easy answer that I know exists. I want to know the result of this command so that I can modify what the script does afterwards:

```psh
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity user1234
```

Comment: Did you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097354/how-do-i-capture-the-output-into-a-variable-from-an-external-process-in-powershe

Comment: @SureshKoya By default `Unlock-ADAccount` doesn't return anything, so there's nothing to capture.

Comment: I have read this, but there has to be something native to powershell.

Comment: Hmm, you are correct Ansgar. Kind of boggles the mind but there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$?` to see if the command was successful or not:

```psh
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity 'user1234'
if ($?) {
  'Account unlocked.'
} else {
  'Unlocking failed.'
}
```

Or you can run the command with the parameter `-PassThru`, so it returns the user object, allowing you to check the lockout status:

```psh
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity 'user1234' -PassThru |
  Get-ADUser -Property 'LockedOut' |
  select -Expand 'LockedOut'
```

You need the additional `Get-ADUser`, because the default property set does not include the property `LockedOut`.