# how to view or scan all open ports in windows server 2012 in powershell or WMI

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, networking

I am working on a windows server 2k12 (VM), is there an easier way beside netstat, to scan/view all open ports/process in windows server with powershell.

*I also use window firewall, but I was told its not sure/all encompassing view open ports, is this true?*

Can you help me wrap the two into a powershell script, and in the second script, how can I get the app names into the commands

1. Scan/display all open ports  `netstat –ano ¦find /i “listening”` this is a console view, and does not have the process name, I have to manually look at the PID in task manager to correlate the process name, *while I mostly use this, I see TCPeye and CurrPorts, but they both seem to be for older versions of the server. Is there a function or feature inside server manager?*
2. Run/Install a bunch of programs located a folder - (for e.g. I have a collection of files I need to install, notepad++, Systernals etc, that I put in the software folder on my desktop)

   `Install-Application -InstallerPath \\server\Desktop$\SoftwareFolder\`(how to find the application/exes in the folder)  `-InstallerParameters "/S" -RegistryKey HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`(some appName) `-RegistryName DisplayVersion -RegistryValue 6.7.8.2 -LogPath \\Server\Software$\logfiles\`

Comment: What have you tried? SO is to help folks with programming problems - not as a script writing service.

Comment: 0. There is no code in your question, meaning you probably haven't tried anything and expect us to do your job 1. `netstat -an` 2. Your question is not understandable (*Start Install*?), and even without only 1 verb, do you think *install a bunch a programs in a folder* is an accurate description of what you need to do ?

Comment: added the code samples

Comment: What is wrong with scripting `PortQry`?

Comment: @user4317867 thanks for that suggestion, did not know it existed, this is what I was looking for some advise based on exp!

Comment: @everest You're welcome, I added more detail and posted an answer.  Please consider accepting that answer if it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PowerShell to script `PortQry.exe` and using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097354/how-do-i-capture-the-output-into-a-variable-from-an-external-process-in-powershe) for help on capturing the output from `PortQry.exe` into a variable for further processing.

As for installing software, I use `Start-Process`

```
$args = "/param1 something /param2 somethingElse"
While (Start-Process -FilePath d:\setup.exe -ArguementList $args -Wait)
 { (Start-Sleep -seconds 5)} #could output a line to the console here
```