# Powershell to .net console application and vice versa

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to know how to call a .net console application from powershell and pass string as parameter. Execution of the next scripts in Powershell script would  be paused until there is a response from the .net console application. Any help would be highly appreciated if someone has done something like this.

[image]

Comment: [https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/16/learn-how-to-load-and-use-powershell-snap-ins/](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/16/learn-how-to-load-and-use-powershell-snap-ins/)

Comment: For one of both ways: [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1) or [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947168/how-to-get-original-binary-data-from-external-command-output-in-powershell/46956134#46956134)