# How to start a new Powershell window with arguments from a script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox and I want to be able to obtain a list of all Virtual Machines using a powershell script (after clicking a button on the gui).

I know you can use the command

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" list vms
```

in cmd/batch to list all VMs but I can't seem to figure out how to display the output with my powershell script. That is why I wanted to create a new powershell window which executes this command so I have a list of VMs.

I tried doing that but nothing happens at all:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms
```

Thanks in advance.

best regards,
John

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this question about output capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097354/how-do-i-capture-the-output-into-a-variable-from-an-external-process-in-powershe) (not related with running command but with 2nd part of your question).

Comment: Maybe try using a ListView to make it look a little less "vibrant". Added a function in there and an example for you.
https://pastebin.com/9RaKU0bk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
cmd /c 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms
```

You should also be able to do this:

```
powershell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms"
```

**Edit**

If you want a new window, use this:

```
Start-Process powerShell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms; pause"
```

The `pause` will wait for you to hit enter before the new window exits.

Comment: Your code works if I just have the command. But my command goes into a Button and nothing happens. This is my code: `$Button4.Add_Click({ cmd /c 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms}) `

Comment: Okay, is there part of the code missing? Are you trying to open a new powershell window and display the results on that? the command is getting executed but you are not receiving it. Even if it opens a new window, it will exit immediately after it executes.

Comment: Yes I am trying to open a new powershell window since I only have the GUI and I need something to list the VMs in. Here's the complete code: https://pastebin.com/UE8Yw5cV

Comment: Try this: `Start-Process powerShell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms; pause"`

Comment: I tried it on your code. It is working for me. However, it returns blank coz i dont have any vms in virtual box. Hoping it will be different for you.

Comment: `Start-Process powerShell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms; pause"` worked for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When running a PowerShell scriptblock from an event (e.g. click) handler, the output of the scriptblock is simply discarded. What you need to do is capture the output in a global variable as follows:

```
$Button4.Add_Click({$global:result =  & 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms})
```

This assigns the output to a global variable `$global:result` which you can then use in other tasks.

> Yes I am trying to open a new powershell window

Do you really want to open a window or do you just want to run a background (asynchronous) job? If you just want a background job, then you should look at `Start-Job`.  One of the problems with using `Start-Process` is that you won't get the results back but you can with PowerShell jobs. If you use `Start-Job`, the code would look like:

```
$Button4.Add_Click({$global:lvmjob =  Start-Job { & 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms}})
```

Then elsewhere in your code, you can receive the job results by doing

```
$data = receive-job -Job $global:lvmjob
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer but is it possible to get the output into a combobox?

Comment: Sure - instead of assigning it to a value, use the `AddRange()` method on the `Items` property on the combobox as in: `$button.add_Click{$combobox.Items.AddRange((& 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' list vms))` where `$combobox` is a variable pointing to your combobox control.