# Powershell executable isn't outputting to STDOUT

Tags: powershell

From a powershell script (with `nuget` installed and on the path), I'm trying to execute an executable (.net, if that matters) ... but for some reason, I can't get the STDOUT to display in the command window.

```
nuget install mdoc -OutputDirectory packages -ExcludeVersion

start-process "packages/mdoc/tools/mdoc.exe" "--version"

echo "done"
```

This *should* output `mdoc 5.7.2` (at the time of this post, current version). But you'll see the nuget output, then `done`.

Any thoughts on why this is not showing up?

Comment: `Start-Process -NoNewWindow`? Or, you could just run the program directly, without `Start-Process`: `& "packages/mdoc/tools/mdoc.exe" --version`.

Comment: I don't understand why so many think you have to use `Start-Process` to get PowerShell to run an executable. This seems to be a wide-spread misunderstanding.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers and @Bill_Stewart I should have been clear ... I *did* try to use the `&` symbol to execute the program, and get the same result.

Comment: But also, I tried adding `-Wait` and `-NoNewWindow`, to no effect

Answer (score 17):

As Ansgar's comment implies: On Windows, `Start-Process` runs console programs *in a new console window* by default, *asynchronously*.

If that program completes quickly, you may see the new console window flash only briefly, as it opens and closes soon thereafter, or you may miss the flash altogether - either way, its output will not show in the *caller's* console window.

<sup>Adding `-Wait` to the `Start-Process` call would make the invocation *synchronous*, and adding `-NoNewWindow` would make it run *in the same console*, yet the calling PowerShell session wouldn't be able to *capture or redirect* the invoked program's output - see below.</sup>

Taking a step back: **Do NOT use `Start-Process`<sup>[1]</sup> if you want to run a console program *synchronously*, with its *standard streams connected to PowerShell's streams* - just invoke such a program *directly*:**

```
packages/mdoc/tools/mdoc.exe --version
```

If the external program's path / name must be *quoted* (because its path contains spaces) and/or it is stored in a *variable*, simply use `&`, the call operator, to invoke it:

```
# Via a quoted string:
& "packages/mdoc/tools/mdoc.exe" --version

# Via a variable:
$exePath = "packages/mdoc/tools/mdoc.exe"
& $exePath --version
```

Using the direct-invocation approach gives you:

- synchronous execution by default
- the ability to capture and/or redirect the invoked program's stdout and stderr streams.
- access to the program's process *exit code* is via PowerShell's [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).

---

To put it all together (based on your later comments):

```
nuget install mdoc -OutputDirectory packages -ExcludeVersion

$exePath = "packages/mdoc/tools/mdoc.exe"

& $exePath --version

"done"
```

This prints the version number - `mdoc 5.7.2` as of this writing - just before printing `done` (verified on Windows PowerShell v5.1.17134.48 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (64-bit; Version 1709, OS Build: 16299.371)).

---

**Optional reading: *capturing* stdout / stderr output from external programs:**

To capture *stdout* output, simply assign the call to a variable:

```
$version = & $exePath --version  # $version receives stdout output as an *array of lines*
```

`$version` receives either a string scalar (single string) if there was only 1 line of output, or an *array* of strings representing the output lines.

To also capture *stderr* output, use redirection `2>&1`:

```
[string[]] $allOutput = & $exePath --version 2>&1
```

Note the cast to `[string[]]`, which ensures that the stderr lines are captured as *strings* too.

- By default, they are captured as `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances, which in *Windows PowerShell* will somewhat confusingly print them as if they were *PowerShell* errors - this problem has been fixed in PowerShell *Core*.
- Conversely, however, if you don't convert the type of the elements of the array that is returned to strings, you can examine each element with `-is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` to determine whether it originated from stdout or stderr.

  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73594732/45375) uses this approach to separate stdout lines from stderr lines after merging with `2>&1`, so that they can be saved to *separate files* (which with `>` in Windows PowerShell requires explicitly stringifying the `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances).

Note: When PowerShell communicates with external programs, **character-encoding issues** come into play: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] Or the underlying .NET API, [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process).

For **guidance** on when `Start-Process` is or isn't appropriate, see [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239)</sup>