# Trying to execute scanstate.exe with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a GUI with PowerShell so it's easier to manipulate scanstate.exe with the different xml files.

However, when I try to execute it, nothing really happens. I'm giving the right location but it can't seem to find it.

```
    Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
    At C:\DigiTool\DigiTool.ps1:1266 char:129
    + ...             Start-Process -FilePath $c -ArgumentList $arglist -Wait - ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I'm probably doing something wrong with the parameters I'm giving along. But I'm not sure what.

```
$c = Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath
$c = (Join-Path $c "USMT\amd64\scanstate.exe")
Write-Host "$c"
Write-Host "$arglist"
Start-Process -FilePath $c -ArgumentList $arglist -Wait -PassThru
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the efficient, PowerShell-idiomatic way to **invoke your command *synchronously, in the same console window, with output connected to PowerShell's streams***:

```
# Determine the executable's file path.
$c = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'USMT\amd64\scanstate.exe'

# Note how &, the call operator is needed for invocation, because the
# executable path is stored in a *variable* (the same would apply if
# a *quoted* string were used).
& $c G:\a_ex03505\10.28.19-14.55.37 /ue:*\* /ui:$user /o /c /i:Custom\MigAppO2019.xml /i:Custom\MigUser_Including_Downloads.xml /i:Migdocs.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeSystemFolders.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeDrives_D_to_Z.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeOneDriveUserFolders.xml
```

If you need to run the command **in a given working directory**:

```bsh
Push-Location $dir

# Note how scanstate.exe, assumed to be located in $dir,
# must be invoked as .\scanstate.exe - with a path component that explicitly
# references the current dir. - in order to be executed from there.
# 
# By design, for security reasons, PowerShell doesn't execute
# executables in the current dir. by file name only - that only works
# for executables in the system's path (dirs. listed in $env:PATH).
.\scanstate.exe G:\a_ex03505\10.28.19-14.55.37 /ue:*\* /ui:$user /o /c /i:Custom\MigAppO2019.xml /i:Custom\MigUser_Including_Downloads.xml /i:Migdocs.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeSystemFolders.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeDrives_D_to_Z.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeOneDriveUserFolders.xml

Pop-Location
```

That is, the above invokes `scanstate.exe` in the current console window and waits for it to finish, passing its output through - though with the *option* to capture / relay / redirect the output for further processing (e.g., `$output = scanstate.exe ...` / `scanstate.exe | ForEach-Object { ... }`, `scanstate.exe 2>$null`)

- **You only need [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) if you want run the command *in a new, separate console window*.**

  - Note that this won't work on *Unix*-like platform with PowerShell *Core*, where `-NoNewWindow` is invariably implied.
- **Console applications never *require* `cmd.exe` for execution** - PowerShell is itself a shell, just like `cmd.exe`, so let *it* handle the invocation, as shown above.

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).

---

You state that in your use case the console window is *hidden*, so if you need the command to run *visibly*, you indeed need `Start-Process` in order to run the command in a *new window*:

```
Start-Process -WorkingDirectory $dir scanstate.exe 'G:\a_ex03505\10.28.19-14.55.37 /ue:*\* /ui:$user /o /c /i:Custom\MigAppO2019.xml /i:Custom\MigUser_Including_Downloads.xml /i:Migdocs.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeSystemFolders.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeDrives_D_to_Z.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeOneDriveUserFolders.xml'
```

Note the use of a single, literal string (`'...'`) to pass all arguments, which implicitly binds to the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

Add `-Wait` to wait for the new window to close.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around my problem with calling cmd directly and passing the command.

> Start-Process cmd.exe -WorkingDirectory $dir -ArgumentList { /k
>   scanstate.exe G:\a_ex03505\10.28.19-14.55.37 /ue:** /ui:$user /o /c
>   /i:Custom\MigAppO2019.xml /i:Custom\MigUser_Including_Downloads.xml
>   /i:Migdocs.xml /i:Custom\ExcludeSystemFolders.xml
>   /i:Custom\ExcludeDrives_D_to_Z.xml
>   /i:Custom\ExcludeOneDriveUserFolders.xml}

Comment: Aside from `cmd.exe` not being required and possibly also not `Start-Process` (unless you need the command to run in a _new window_), I suggest not using script blocks `{ ... }` to pass an argument to the `[string]`-typed `-ArgumentList` parameter: While convenient from a quoting perspective, it creates the mistaken impression that you can use variables or expressions inside the script block, which doesn't work in this scenario.