# RoboCopy.exe switches not working in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm going to try to make this question very simple. If I run the following, it works without issue:

```
$localData = "C:\"
$netData = "\\OtherPC\shared\"
Start-Process "RoboCopy.exe" -argumentlist " `"$localData`" `"$netData`" "
```

However, as soon as I add any switches (see below), it does not work. No errors to be seen.

```
$localData = "C:\"
$netData = "\\OtherPC\shared\"
Start-Process "RoboCopy.exe" -argumentlist " `"$localData`" `"$netData`" /copyall"
```

It's been a real pain to try and fix, any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Fixed, and here is the final working syntax:

```
$localFiles = "C:\Users\"
$netFiles = "\\netLocation\migration\Users\"

Start-Process "RoboCopy.exe" -NoNewWindow -argumentlist " `"$localFiles\`" `"$netFiles\`" /s /r:1 /w:5 /mt:16"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>As an aside: Your use of `Start-Process` may be intentional to run a lengthy operation *asynchronously*, in a *new window*, but the more typical case is to execute console applications such as `Robocopy.exe` *synchronously*, in the *same window*, in which case you need to call them *directly* (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375). An alternative to asynchronous execution in a new window is to use a [background job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs).</sup>

**You have to *double* a trailing `\` in your path arguments if they (end up) enclosed in `"..."`** in the command line (ultimately) submitted:

Simply define your variable values with a trailing `\\`, which should make your command work:

```
$localData = 'C:\\'
$netData = '\\OtherPC\shared\\'
```

<sup>Another solution (on Windows) for *file paths* specifically is to insert a *space* between the trailing `\` and the `"`. This works, because the file-system WinAPI calls ignore trailing spaces in paths.</sup>

The reason that `\\` is needed at the end is that **`RoboCopy.exe` (and, indeed, virtually *all* external programs) interpret sequence `\"` as an *escaped* `"` character** rather to be used *verbatim* rather than having *syntactic* function.

If you need to append the extra `\` *programmatically*, use the following:

```
$localDataEscaped = $localData -replace '\\$', '\\'
$netDataEscaped = $netData -replace '\\$', '\\'
```

---

**Debugging tip for `Start-Process` calls**:

(Temporarily) add `-NoNewWindow -Wait` to the call, which makes the command output appear in the *same window*, giving you a chance to inspect it; by default, `Start-Process` runs the command in a new window (on Windows) that *automatically closes* when the command finishes, potentially not giving you enough time to see the output.