# powershell run cmd with spaces in argument

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to add a watcher for a folder, once file is created, start a program

```
$script= "C:\test.py"
$watcher.Path ="e:\my folder\test folder\dropbox"    

Start-Process cmd -Argument "/k python $script $path"
```

Problem is that, this will always get me error saying e:\my no such file

I know this is an issue with space, but I tried the following, still get same error

```
Start-Process cmd -Argument "/k python $script '$path'"
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *escaped embedded* double quotes with `Start-Process`:

```
$script= "C:\test.py"
$path = "e:\my folder\test folder\dropbox"    

Start-Process cmd -Argument "/k python $script `"$path`""
```

Without that, the spaces in the `$path` value break the path into *multiple* arguments when `cmd` receives the arguments.

`` `" `` embeds a verbatim `"` inside a `"..."` string.

As an aside:

- If your intent is to run a command *asynchronously*, in a *new window* (on Windows), as your command suggests, `Start-Process` is indeed the right tool.
- By contrast, do *not* use `Start-Process` if you want to run other console applications (such as `cmd`) *synchronously*, in the *same window*; in that event, just invoke the console application *directly* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run a powershell cmd to parse the input, specifically to get the version of chrome running on the server.

```
     String version = null;
     String command = "powershell.exe (Get-Item \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\").VersionInfo";
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
     process.getOutputStream().close();
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));       
     String line = reader.readLine();
     while(line!=null){
         if(line.matches("[0-9]{2,3}\\.[0-9]{1,2}\\..*")){
             version = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("."));
         }             
         line = reader.readLine();                
     }
```

This failed with the error indicating that the command was split at the spaces in the path.

I replaced the escaped double quotes with single quotes and it worked:

```
String command = "powershell.exe (Get-Item 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe').VersionInfo";
```