# Using Powershell Start-Process to run a Cmd Batch file, how to read the error level from the Cmd Batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

Assume I have two files, `script.ps1` and `filename.cmd`, and I run `.\script.ps1` from a Powershell prompt:

script.ps1

```
Write-Host "About to run filename.cmd"
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath filename.cmd -NoNewWindow -Wait
Write-Host "proc: [$proc]"
Write-Host "LASTEXITCODE: [$LASTEXITCODE]
```

filename.cmd

```
@echo off
ECHO File returns ErrorLevel=1
exit /b 1
```

Output:

```
About to run filename.cmd
proc: []
LASTEXITCODE: []
```

Both `proc` and `LASTEXITCODE` are `$null`. My understanding was that somehow I could access the `ErrorCode`?

How do I read the failed error level (in this case `1`) in my Powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To synchronously execute console applications, including batch files, call them *directly*, do *not* use `Start-Process`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).

Therefore:

```
Write-Host "About to run filename.cmd"
# For security reasons, PowerShell requires that you explicitly
# signal the intent to run an executable located *in the current directory*,
# hence the need for `./` (or `.\`)
# Only direct invocation of external programs (batch files) sets
# the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable.
./filename.cmd
Write-Host "LASTEXITCODE: [$LASTEXITCODE]
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) outputs *nothing* by default - except if you pass the `-PassThru` switch, in which case a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance representing the newly started process is returned.

Assuming you've also specified `-Wait`, as in your case, you can then access the returned object's `.ExitCode` property to determine the exit code immediately afterwards.

Note that [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) `$LASTEXITCODE` is only set after *direct* invocation of external programs, as shown above.

Therefore, if you were to use `Start-Process` - which is *not* necessary in this case, as explained above - you'd have to use the following:

```
Write-Host "About to run filename.cmd"
$proc = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath filename.cmd -NoNewWindow -Wait
Write-Host "proc: [$proc]"
Write-Host "exit coe: [$($proc.ExitCode)]
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I ended up using ```Invoke-Expression -Command "filename.cmd" | Out-Host``` so that I could mock the call in my Pester tests, which appears to have worked like a charm using ```$LASTEXITCODE```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @satoukum. As a matter of habit, I suggest [avoiding `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/), so perhaps `Invoke-Command { ./filename.cmd }` is the better alternative.