# Powershell ps1 script runs bat file but CMD screen closes after execution

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

This is my code:

```
set-location [PATH]
$A = Start-Process -FilePath .\refresh.bat -Wait

set-location C:\
```

When executed in powershell, the system opens a Command prompt window and executes the bat file without issue. The problem is that the window closes and I cannot see if there was an error if it succeeds.

I want to keep the CMD window open.

I also tried at the end of the bat file:

```
:END
cmd /k
```

but no luck.

Comment: `Pause` will do the trick. Most commands of cmd are also supported on powershell. So u dont need to invoke a cmd from powershell. You can directly run on powershell or even translate it to powershell. That way, you can perform error handling and such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **unless you specifically need to run the batch file in a *new window*, do not use `Start-Process` - use *direct invocation* instead**, which is implicitly *synchronous* and allows you to *capture or redirect output*:

```
# Invoke the batch file synchronously (wait for it to exit)
# and capture its (standard) output in variable $A
# To print the batch file's output to the console instead, just use:
#    .\refresh.bat
$A = .\refresh.bat
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976113/45375) for more information.

Also note `Start-Process` never allows you to capture the invoked program's *output* directly (you can only redirect it to *files* with `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardOutput`); your specific command captures *nothing*<sup>[1]</sup> in `$A`; adding `-PassThru` does return something, but not the program's output, but a process-information object ([`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process)).

**If you *do* need to run the batch file in a new window** and want to **keep that window open**:

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath cmd -ArgumentList '/k .\refresh.bat'
```

<sup>Relying on positional parameter binding, the above can be simplified to:

 `Start-Process -Wait cmd '/k .\refresh.bat'`</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, `$A` is assigned the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton, which in most contexts behaves like `$null`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mklement0 with your post gave me the solution I wanted. This is how I solved it.

```
set-location [PATH]
$A = Start-Process -FilePath .\refresh.bat -Wait -NoNewWindow
set-location C:\
```

**-NoNewWindow** allowed me to run my batch in the same powershell window getting the feedback of the bat file. That way I have errors if any and success status if no errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear my answer was helpful - note that a simpler alternative is to use direct invocation without capturing the output: `.\refresh.bat` by itself is enough.