# PowerShell Start-Process with -ArgumentList doesn't work

Tags: powershell

A very easy line in a powershell script

```
Start-Process -FilePath displayswitch -ArgumentList "/extend"
```

It is supposed to extend my screen. Yet it doesn't work because there is something wrong with the ArgumentList. What is it?

Comment: Does it work when you run the command without `Start-Process`?

Comment: @Olaf I already changed my script around to use Start-Job instead, but this problem angered me as this should not require me going around googling for 15 minutes and don't come up with any results.

Comment: ... and to extend my question: does it work in `CMD`?

Comment: @Olaf Yes, it works in CMD.

Comment: Cool ... and that's not an option for you? How do you run it there?

Comment: If your script is actually more than just this command you may share this. Did you try to run the command without `Start-Process` or `Start-Job`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, do not use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) to invoke CLIs (command-line interfaces; i.e., programs that accept command-line arguments), unless you explicitly want to launch them *asynchronously, in a new window* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) for background information.

In the case at hand - for reasons unknown to me<sup>[1]</sup> - `Start-Process` additionally seems to prevent the `displayswitch.exe` executable from functioning properly *when arguments are passed* (the syntax of your `Start-Process` command is correct).

However, that is a moot point if you invoke `displayswitch.exe` *directly*, which is generally the right choice for CLIs:<sup>[2]</sup>

```
displayswitch.exe /extend
```

---

<sup>[1] The problem *may* be related to the fact that `displayswitch.exe` is a *GUI-subsystem* rather than a *console-subsystem* application. That is, it doesn't allocate a console window for itself and operates asynchronously when called from an existing console window. Using `Start-Process` therefore makes the executable run without a console window. That said, running `displayswitch.exe /extend` from the Windows Run dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>), where no console window is involved either, works correctly.</sup>

<sup>[2] Given that `displayswitch.exe` is a *GUI-subsystem* application, it will act *asynchronously* even in *direct* invocation, but I assume that's not a problem here. If your `Start-Process` command had worked, it would have been asynchronous too. Adding `-Wait` to a `Start-Process` call makes it synchronous, and you can emulate this behavior in direct invocation by piping to `Out-Null`. However, due to how `displayswitch.exe` is implemented, even `displayswitch.exe /extend | Out-Null` doesn't result in fully synchronous operation.</sup>