# How can I execute PHP code with Powershell?

Tags: php, powershell

I'm building a website and I want to monitor a folder for changes, and when those changes happen I want to start my PHP script, which runs an SQL query to builds my table.
Here is the script: This is largely from [nixda](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created), so credit goes to them

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\xampp\mysql\data\db\"
    $watcher.Filter = "*myTable.csv*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                start-process -filepath \\server\path\to\php\runme.php
                Add-content "\\server\path\to\log\log.txt" -value $logline
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What you ask for works already by what you ask for. So WHAT is your problem?

Comment: php code is executed by php - as usual. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @hakre my problem is I want to execute the php script as soon as a .csv file is placed into  the monitored folder. I'm using powershell to monitor the folder and I want to use powershell to execute runme.php after detecting the new file. What I have tried is using Invoke-Command to run the .php as it is stored on a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To synchronously execute console applications or batch files and capture their output, call them *directly* (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`), do *not* use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).
- `.php` script files are, at least by default, *not* directly executable, so you should invoke them by passing the script file path to `php.exe` as shown below (which runs them *synchronously*, with their stdout and stderr streams connected to PowerShell's streams, if needed):

  - By default, if you do invoke a `.php` script-file path directly or directly pass it to `Start-Process`'s `-FilePath` parameter, that script is *opened for editing* rather than getting executed.

```sh
php.exe -f \\server\path\to\php\runme.php
```