# Issues running script to run remote .exe

Tags: powershell

If I run the below script on the computer it works as expected and installs.

```
Start-Process "C:\Test_Software\TestConfigApp" " -s"
```

But I need to run this remotely. So this is the code I have but it is not working. $Computer is defined and is the correct device. What am I doing wrong? I have other Scripts that I run remotely to this device so I know I am getting to it correctly and not getting blocked.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "C:\Test_Software\TestConfigApp" " -s"}
```

Comment: To recap: The answer below explains why your approach _fundamentally_ cannot work, irrespective of the specific executable being invoked, and, as such, your question is answered _as asked_. If you add `-Wait` to the `Start-Process` call, as recommended in the answer, and it still doesn't work, the problem must lie _with your specific executable_ - absent any information about this specific executable, your problem cannot be solved. I recommend asking a separate question about your specific executable.

Answer (score 2):

[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) launches a process *asynchronously* by default. That is, control is instantly returned to PowerShell, even if the launched process is still running.

- In a *local* invocation, the launched process lives on *independently* of the calling process.
- In a *remote* invocation, the remote session ending *automatically terminates* processes launched via `Start-Process`.

This asymmetry exists for technical reasons and is explained in [GitHub issue #16001](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16001).

---

This means that your `C:\Test_Software\TestConfigApp` process most likely never gets a chance to run to completion, given that your remote session ends right after the `Start-Process` call.

To ensure that it does, add `-Wait` to the `Start-Process` call:

```sh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process -Wait 'C:\Test_Software\TestConfigApp' '-s'
}
```

Note:

- Remoting commands run in an invisible window station, in which some *GUI* applications may refuse to run. When that happens, you'll need to look for a logging mechanism that can help you troubleshoot; perhaps the remote machine's event log provides clues.
- If, by contrast, `C:\Test_Software\TestConfigApp` happens to be a *console* application, you can achieve the same effect - synchronous execution - with *direct invocation* (which is *generally* the right way to invoke console applications - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375)):

```sh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
  # Only if the application is a *console* application.
  C:\Test_Software\TestConfigApp -s
}
```

Comment: Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process -Wait 'C:\Test_Software\TestConfigApp' '-s'
}
Didn't work. I had already tried the "-Wait" and there is absolutely no activity on the remote computer

Comment: @mr_evans2u: This answer explains why your code _as posted in your question_ won't work, for which there is a good _general_ explanation. If `-Wait` doesn't help, and no error is returned, the implication is that _your specific application_,  `C:\Test_Software\TestConfigApp`, is failing silently (or with a GUI notification you won't be able to see, but that would _block_ the `Invoke-Command` call indefinitely).

Comment: @mr_evans2u: Remoting commands run in an invisible window station, in which some GUI applications may refuse to run. You'll need to look for a logging mechanism that can help you troubleshoot; perhaps the remote machine's event log provides clues.