# powershell Pipe Operators

Tags: windows, powershell, exit-code, start-process

I executed the following three powershell commands. The first two commands returned no results, and the third command returned results. The main difference between the three commands is the use of the wait argument and parentheses.

> PS C:\Users> Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec' -ArgumentList '/I C:\Users\Downloads\Everything-1.4.1.1015.x64.msi -quiet' -PassThru | Foreach-Object -Process { $_.exitcode }

> PS C:\Users> Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec' -ArgumentList '/I C:\Users\Downloads\Everything-1.4.1.1015.x64.msi -quiet' -PassThru -wait | Foreach-Object -Process { $_.exitcode }

> PS C:\Users> (Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec' -ArgumentList '/I C:\Users\Downloads\Everything-1.4.1.1015.x64.msi -quiet' -PassThru -Wait) | Foreach-Object -Process { $_.exitcode }

> 1619

I test another two commands, and the difference between them was the use of parentheses. Both commands returned results no matter with parentheses.

> PS C:\Users> Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec' -ArgumentList '/I C:\Users\Downloads\Everything-1.4.1.1015.x64.msi -quiet' -PassThru | Foreach-Object -Process { $_.id }

> 22980

> PS C:\Users> (Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec' -ArgumentList '/I C:\Users\Downloads\Everything-1.4.1.1015.x64.msi -quiet' -PassThru -Wait) | Foreach-Object -Process { $_.id }

> 8064

Thanks for explanation for -wait parameter. I still confused with the difference caused by parentheses. Hope for more replies.

Comment: The `ExitCode` property cannot be populated _before the process exits_ - `-Wait` causes `Start-Process` to wait until the target process has exited before returning

Comment: command 2 and 3 both use -Wait, but command 2 returned no results.

Comment: Please review the code you've posted - only the 3rd one has the `-Wait` switch

Comment: Sorry about posting the wrong command. I corrected it.

Comment: How does new edit relate to the question being asked before? It's not clear what exactly you want to know

Comment: I understand the difference caused by the wait argument, but I also want to know the difference caused by parentheses.

Comment: I see what you mean, I believe the parentheses are holding the object in memory and once the `ExitCode` is recorded it passes that object to the `ForEach-Object`, may be wrong tho

Comment: Good point, @Santiago: `(...)` forces waiting for `Start-Process` _as a whole_ to exit, and (with `-Wait`) only _that_ guarantees that the process has truly exited; by contrast, without `(...)` the newly launched process is emitted _to the pipeline right away_, before it has terminated, and that's why `ForEach-Object` cannot yet access `.ExitCode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The main difference between the three commands is the use of the `-Wait` argument and parentheses

To build on [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)'s helpful comment:

**It is *primarily* the use of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s `-Wait` switch that is required**:

- Without `-Wait`, `Start-Process` runs *asynchronously*.
- Without `-PassThru`, `Start-Process` produces *no output*.

While `-PassThru` makes `Start-Process` output a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance representing the newly launched process, *unless `-Wait` is *also* present* that instance's `.ExitCode` property *has no value yet*, because the launched process typically *hasn't exited yet*.

***Additionally*, parentheses (`(...)`) are required *too***, because `Start-Process` emits the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance representing the newly launched process to the pipeline (as received by `ForEach-Object`) *right away*, and *then* waits for the process to exit. By using `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), you're forcing a wait for `Start-Process` *itself* to exit, at which point the `Process`' instance `.ExitCode` property *is* available, thanks to `-Wait`.

In general, wrapping a command in `(...)` forces collecting its output in *full*, *up front* - which includes waiting for it to *exit* - before the results are passed through the pipeline (as opposed to the *streaming* (one-by-on output) behavior that is the default, which happens *while the command is still running*).

Therefore, the following works - but *see the bottom section for a simpler alternative*:

```sh
# Note: With (...), you could also pipe the output to ForEach-Object, as in
#       your question, but given that there's by definition only *one* 
#       output object, that is unnecessary.
(
  Start-Process -PassThru -Wait -FilePath 'msiexec' -ArgumentList '/i C:\Users\Downloads\Everything-1.4.1.1015.x64.msi -quiet' 
).ExitCode
```

It follows from the above that using *two separate statements* would work too (given that any statement *runs to completion* before executing the next):

```sh
$process = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait -FilePath 'msiexec' -ArgumentList '/i C:\Users\Downloads\Everything-1.4.1.1015.x64.msi -quiet' 
$process.ExitCode
```

---

**`msiexec.exe` is *unusual*** in that:

- it is a *GUI*(-subsystem) executable (as opposed to a *console*(-subsystem) executable), which therefore - even when invoked *directly* - runs *asynchronously*.
- yet it reports a meaningful process *exit code* that the caller may be interested in, requiring the caller to wait for its exit (termination) in order to determine this exit code.

As an aside: For invoking *console* applications, `Start-Process` is *not* the right tool in general, except in *unusual* scenarios - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).

---

An **simpler alternative** to using `msiexec` with `Start-Process -PassThru -Wait` is to **use *direct* invocation via `cmd /c`**, which ensures both (a) *synchronous invocation* and (b) that PowerShell reflects `msiexec`'s exit code in its [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode):

```sh
cmd /c 'msiexec /i C:\Users\Downloads\Everything-1.4.1.1015.x64.msi -quiet'
$LASTEXITCODE  # output misexec's exit code
```

Note: If the `msiexec` command line needs to include PowerShell variable values, pass an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) to `cmd /c` instead and - as with [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) strings - use *embedded* double quoting around embedded arguments, as necessary.

Comment: when I want to get exitcode, I must use parentheses. when I want to get id, Whether or not I use parentheses has no effect.

Comment: @jiligulu The `Id` is assigned on process _startup_, so that's immediately available regardless of whether you wait for the process to exit or not. It's a simple question of timing.

Comment: @jiligulu, you are correct: the`(...)` are _also_ needed in order to get an `.ExitCode` value - please see my update. However, as @Mathias points out, _other_ properties of the `Process` instance, such as `.Id` are available right away.