# Powershell Invoke Command is not working for Remote Machine and did not returning any error message

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to install my MSI package on the remote machine. Below is the script I am using. In this script, The invoke command execution is not returning any error or success message.but the copy command is working fine. anyone help to find the issue.

```
param([String]$MSILocation,[String]$RemoteComputerName,[String]$UserName,[String]$Password,[String]$Port,[String]$AccessKey,[String]$Protocol)
$ServeAdminPassword=  $Password  | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName,$ServeAdminPassword)
$hostname = hostname
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteComputerName -Credential $cred
$cpy   = Copy-Item $MSILocation  -Destination "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\" -ToSession $session
try
{
    $result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock  {
        param($hostname,$Port,$Protocol)
         $value = msiexec /i "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\software.msi" SERVERNAME=$hostname PORTNO=$Port PROTOCOL=$Protocol /qb /forcerestart
        calc.exe
    } -ArgumentList $hostname,$Port,$Protocol | Select-Object value

}
catch
{
    $result = $error[0]
    echo $result
}
```

Comment: What is $AccessKey?  Also msiexec runs in the background unless you wait for it.  Why run calc.exe?

Comment: $Acceskey  - this parameter is used in my msi . calc.exe - i added this to test whether the command is executing in remote machine or not. but it is not invoked in my remote machine

Comment: @js2010 do i need to add any wait cmd. after msiexec

Comment: Remove `Select-Object Value` and see if it returns anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `msiexec` is unusual in that it runs *asynchronously* by default, so you need to *explicitly wait for its termination* in order to learn its exit code.
- The exit code is never returned via *output* (stdout); instead, depending on invocation technique, you must query a `Process` object's `.ExitCode` property (when you use `Start-Process -Wait -PassThru`) or use the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) (when you use the technique shown below).

A simple way to force synchronous execution and have the exit code be reflected in `$LASTEXITCODE` is to call via `cmd /c`:

```
# Call msiexec and wait for its termination.
cmd /c "msiexec /i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\software.msi SERVERNAME=$hostname PORTNO=$Port PROTOCOL=$Protocol /qb /forcerestart"
$LASTEXITCODE # Output msiexec's exit code.
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70691014/45375) for details.