# PowerShell, getting string syntax correct in 7-zip script

Tags: string, powershell, 7zip, quotation-marks

I can't seem to solve this, been struggling with it for a while (maybe it's simple; I just can't see it as I've been looking at it for so long).
I can get the 7z.exe syntax to work, but when I try and put it together into a simple script, it fails.

e.g., if I run `.\zip.ps1 "C:\test\test.zip" "C:\test\test1.txt" "C:\test\test2.txt*`

Instead of zipping up the 2 files required, it zips up everything in the C:\test folder, completely ignoring my arguments.

How can I adjust the below string syntax so that 7z.exe will correctly respect the input arguments and compress them from within a PowerShell script?

```
"Received $($args.Count) files:"
$parent = Split-Path (Split-Path $args[0]) -Leaf
$sevenzip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$zipname = "$($parent) $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss').zip"
$args_line = $args | foreach-object { "`"$_`"" }
# $args_line = '"' + $($args -join """ """) + '"'   # Want to use """ here so that it can capture not only files with spaces, but files with ' in the filename
''
"Zip Name  : $zipname"
''
"Arguments : $args_line"
''
if (Test-Path $sevenzip) {
    if (Test-Path "C:\0\$zipname") { rm "C:\0\$zipname" -Force }
    ''
    'String output of the line to run:'
    "& ""$sevenzip"" a -r -tzip ""C:\0\$zipname"" $args_line"   # Taking this output and pasting onto console works.
''
    & "$sevenzip" a -r -tzip "C:\0\$zipname" "$args_line"   # This does not work
} else {
    "7z.exe was not found at '$sevenzip', please check and try again"
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 22 bytes (1 KiB)

Scan WARNINGS for files and folders:

1 : The system cannot find the file specified.
----------------
```

Comment: Is this a typo… ```"$zrgs_line"``` that should be ```"$args_line”``` instead?

Comment: It is, thanks, I've updated it, but I still get errors as above.

Comment: You possibly need to specify ```$args_line``` as an array rather than a string as Powershell may be munging your string with additional quotes when it builds the command. Try ```$args_line = $args | foreach-object { “`”$_`”” }``` instead, or even just simply ```$args_line = $args```. I can’t test this myself right now, so it’s a bit of a shot to nothing :-)…

Comment: still not working unfortunately. Again, if I take the full string as generated on the line before the actual zip, it works perfectly, but the `7z.exe` line inside the script fails every time ...

Comment: Either add 7z to the path or run it directly like: `C:\Program\` Files\7-Zip\7z`.  Otherwise the & args have to be an array if not spelled out.  This is a common question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pass `$args` *directly* to your `& "$sevenzip"` call**:

```
& "$sevenzip" a -r -tzip "C:\0\$zipname" $args
```

This makes PowerShell pass the array elements as individual arguments, *automatically* enclosing them in `"..."` if needed (based on whether they contain spaces).

Using arrays as arguments for *external programs* is in effect an implicit form of array-based [splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting); thus, you could alternatively pass `@args`.

---

Generally, note that in direct invocation<sup>[1]</sup> **you cannot pass *multiple* arguments to an external program via a *single string***; that is, something like `"$args_line"` cannot be expected to work, because it is passed as a *single* argument to the target program.

---

If you want to ***emulate* the resulting part of the command line, for *display* purposes**:

```
($argListForDisplay = $args.ForEach({ ($_, "`"$_`"")[$_ -match ' '] })) -join ' '
```

Note:

- Each argument is *conditionally* enclosed in `"..."` - namely based on whether it contains at least one *space* - and the resulting tokens are joined to form a single, space-separated list (string).
- The assumption is that no argument has embedded `"` chars.

---

**A simplified example:**

```
& {  # an ad-hoc script block that functions like a script or function

  # Construct the argument list *for display*
  $argListForDisplay = $args.ForEach({ ($_, "`"$_`"")[$_ -match ' '] }) -join ' '

  @"
The following is the equivalent of:

  Write-Output $argListForDisplay

"@

 # Pass $args *directly*
 # Simply prints the argument received one by one, each on its own line.
 # Note: With PowerShell-native commands, generally use @args instead (see below). 
 Write-Output $args

} firstArg 'another Arg' lastArg  # sample pass-through arguments
```

Output:

```
The following is the equivalent of:

  Write-Output firstArg "another Arg" lastArg

firstArg
another Arg
lastArg
```

Note: `Write-Output` is used in lieu of an external program for convenience. Technically, you'd have to use `@args` instead of `$args` in order to pass the array elements as individual, positional arguments, but, as stated, this is the default behavior with externals programs. `Write-Output`, as a PowerShell-native command, receives the array *as a whole*, as a *single argument* when `$args` is used; it just so happens to process that array the same way as if its elements had been passed as individual arguments.

---

<sup>[1] You *can* use a single string as an `-ArgumentList` value for [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process). However, `Start-Process` is usually the wrong tool for invoking console applications such as `7z.exe` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).</sup>

Comment: This is a very useful example for me, as the right way to pass arguments to other programs or cmdlets. I think this will apply to many other situations for some things that I'm doing; thanks for the detailed explanation, much appreciated.