# Run Batch Script from PowerShell and pass long options

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch script that works as expected:
`operationalhealth.bat --hostname machine.domain.com --username admin --password admin1 --outputDir C:\Temp`

I am trying to trigger this script from PowerShell and pass the "long options" arguments, without success.

I have tried:

Example 1:

```
$scriptPath = "C:\path\to\operationalhealth.bat"
$arguments = "--hostname", "machine.domain.com", "--username", "admin", "--password", "admin1", "--outputDir", "C:\Temp"

Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c", "$scriptPath", $arguments -Wait
```

Example 2:

```
Start-Process "C:\path\to\operationalhealth.bat" -ArgumentList "--hostname machine.domain.com --username admin --password admin1 --outputDir C:\Temp" -Wait
```

In each instance, command prompt opens but does not seem to have received the arguments. I'm sure this is a vague syntax issue, but I can't wrap my head around what the proper format is. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As an aside: To synchronously execute console applications or batch files in the current console window, call them _directly_ (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`). This also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via `$LASTEXITCODE`. Do _not_ use `Start-Process` (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375). [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

Comment: I've done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$scriptPath = "C:\path\to\operationalhealth.bat"
$outputDir = "C:\Temp"
& $scriptPath --hostname machine.domain.com --username admin --password admin1 --outputDir $outputDir
```

Comment: @baddist if you don't mind, mark this answer as a solution