# Why does 7zip mmt work better with PowerShell's new Parallel?

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I have a PowerShell (v7.3.7) script that iterates through files and archives them using 7-Zip. When using 7-Zip's multi-threading option `-mmt`, the script takes 180 seconds to execute in my case. However, if I utilize [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) with `-ThrottleLimit 1`, the execution time drops down to 50 seconds. On an interesting sidenote, altering the throttle limit to other numbers doesn't improve the execution time further, and in fact, increasing it beyond 50% of my logical cores leads to a longer execution time.

I would have thought that 7-Zip's own multi-threading would be sufficient to fully utilize my cores, but it seems only with `-Parallel` (even at `-ThrottleLimit 1`), 7-Zip starts using my cores efficiently. I have verified this by disabling `-mmt` (using `-mmt=off`), which brings the execution time back to its original 180 seconds.

I'm curious as to how PowerShell's `-Parallel` parameter affects 7-Zip's `-mmt` capability. I've been at this for a while with ChatGPT4 trying to rule things out, but we're both (heh) stumped. I suspect this has to be related to how `-Parallel` spins up a new *runspace* and somehow the underlying architecture has an effect on how cpus are made available for the script executed in this namespace. But it shouldn't.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation or have insights into why this might be happening?

Below is my script for reference:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$password
)

# The 7-Zip executable path (modify if necessary)
$7zipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

# Ensure 7-Zip is installed
if (!(Test-Path $7zipPath)) {
    throw "7-Zip not found at path $7zipPath"
}

$items = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ | Where-Object { $_.Extension -ne ".ps1" }

$timer = Measure-Command {
    $items | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        $item = $_
        $name = $using:name
        $password = $using:password
        $7zipPath = $using:7zipPath

        $guid = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
        $zipFileWithoutPassword = "${name}_${guid}.zip"
        $zipFileWithPassword = "${name}${guid}.zip"

        # Create a non-password protected zip with no compression
        $argListNoPassword = "a -tzip ""$zipFileWithoutPassword"" ""$item"" -mx=0 -mmt"
        Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "$7zipPath" -ArgumentList $argListNoPassword -NoNewWindow

        # Add password protection to the zip using 7-Zip with AES256
        $argListWithPassword = "a -tzip ""$zipFileWithPassword"" ""$zipFileWithoutPassword"" -p$password -mem=AES256 -mx=0 -mmt"
        Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "$7zipPath" -ArgumentList $argListWithPassword -NoNewWindow

        # Remove non-password protected zip
        Remove-Item -Path $zipFileWithoutPassword
    } -ThrottleLimit 1
}

Write-Host "Total execution time: $($timer.TotalSeconds) seconds"
```

(Just save this to a .ps1 file and it will zip everything in the current folder when executed, excluding .ps1 files. Run it with: `./the_script.ps1 archive-entry somepassword`.)

Comment: That is mystifying, especially given that `ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 1 -Parallel { ... }` should only _slow things down_ (all thread-management overhead, with no parallelism). It's also not clear why `7zip`'s behavior should change when called from a different thread.

Comment: As an aside: To synchronously execute console applications such as `7z.exe` in the current console window, call them _directly_ (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`). This also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via `$LASTEXITCODE`. Do _not_ use `Start-Process` (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375). [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

Comment: Another aside: In PowerShell 7+, you can simplify your `Get-ChildItem` call to: `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath . -Exclude *.ps1` (add `-File` to limit matching to files only; use of `-LiteralPath` rater than `-Path` is then crucial, due to a bug; due to additional bugs, in Windows PowerShell, it is `-Path` that must be used with `-Exclude`, and adding `-File` doesn't work at all).

Comment: Are you sure your measuring is correct and the 2nd run with `ForEach-Object -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 1` isn't just faster because the files are already cached?

Comment: @zett42 I'm a simple guy, I just delete the zips and try again. I'll say this though, messing with the _throttle_ and _mmt_ parameters, occasionally changing them back (so pretty random config switch arounds), the measurements _are_ consistent.

Comment: Looks to me like the command only uses one thread in processes explorer, compared to 8 threads when making a .7z file with lzma2 compression.

Comment: Also, bzip2 is almost twice as fast as 7z, and can multithread in 7zip.