# In Powershell Core is it possible to get native progress output to console host window when running from within a script block?

Tags: powershell, console, output

I would like to get progress-output from native programs like restic backup or yt-dlp in powershell, even though I'm running the program from within a block like this. Is it possible for the inner script block to output to the console like when executing it directly? I have control over the executeWithPidLock implementation.

```
executeWithPidLock {
  .\restic.exe -r temp-repo backup 'C:\Tools\AlwaysMouseWheel'
}
```

I know I can run with new window like this and get console progress output, which is not that bad, but not really what I want, as I don't want window popping up when running from Task scheduler:

```
measure-command {
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath "./restic" -ArgumentList @("-r", "temp-repo","backup",'C:\Tools\') -PassThru -Wait
    $process.WaitForExit()
}
```

**EDIT (to add some extra needed info, based on first answer):**

An option is to manually pipe to out-host, as correctly suggested by mklement0.

```
Measure-Command {  yt-dlp "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NS5NKykuQno" | out-host}
```

However this will not behave like directly in console for progress information. For 'restic' it completely skips the progress information. For 'yt-dlp' it prints each %-line, where the direct execution deletes each old line, like this.

```
[download]  33.3% of  242.55MiB at    6.74MiB/s ETA 00:23
[download]  33.4% of  242.55MiB at    2.00MiB/s ETA 01:20
[download]  33.4% of  242.55MiB at    2.70MiB/s ETA 00:59
[download]  33.4% of  242.55MiB at    3.75MiB/s ETA 00:43
```

If it is not possible in Powershell 7.3.9 to execute a native command and get unmolested progress info, that is a valid answer (though a link to some doc would be greatly appreciated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general advice:

- To synchronously execute console applications or batch files in the current console window, call them *directly* (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`). This also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via `$LASTEXITCODE`. Do *not* use `Start-Process` (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375). [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

---

Heeding this advice also solves your specific problem:

- PowerShell *streams* the output from external (console) applications *line by line* to the pipeline, so you can see or process lines *as they're being emitted*, even from inside a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`).
- A script block passed to [`Measure-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command) is a special case, as the latter explicitly *suppresses* output from the commands in the script block.

You can work around this - for *display-only* output - with [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host), as the following example shows, which also demonstrates the streaming nature of the output:

```
Measure-Command {
  cmd /c 'echo 1 & timeout 2 >NUL & echo err >&2 & echo 2' *>&1 | Out-Host
}
```

`1` will print right away, even though the command hasn't finished executing yet.

Note the use of [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `*>&1` to ensure that *stderr* output is output too:

- Redirected stderr lines print in *red* and - in *Windows PowerShell* - the *first* stderr line prints *as if it were a PowerShell error* (no longer a problem in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).

  - Separately, there *is* a bug that affects PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x up to at least 7.3.10: in regular console windows (`conhost.exe`) (as opposed to in *Windows Terminal*), the ANSI/VT escape-code based coloring is *rendered incorrectly* in a pipeline involving a native (external program) - see [GitHub issue #18771](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18771), which was inappropriately closed.
- To avoid that, insert a `ForEach-Object ToString` pipeline segment before `Out-Host`.

If you invoked the script block *directly* (typically via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)), you wouldn't need `Out-Host` and the external program's output would be streamed to PowerShell's success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams)

-- EDIT (by OP)

So if you control your function yourself, you can do this:

```
function executeBlockWithCall([ScriptBlock]$Block) {
    Write-Host "Do stuff before..."
    # Invoke-Command $Block # this also works to get progress- output to main console
    & $Block
    Write-Host "...and after"
}
executeBlockWithCall { yt-dlp "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NS5NKykuQno" }
```

and the progress output will stream unmolested to your console window.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I had almost given up hope that it existed. 

Also thank you for the link to your other very detailed answer. 

What I needed was at the end there with the call operator. Though the out-host is also-helpful for cases like Measure-Command, though out-host messes with progress. I've added an example at the end, because the answer I was looking for was almost drowning in the rest of the info.