# How to escape special characters in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parameters, escaping

When my PowerShell script runs, it prompts the user for a password parameter. That password can contain any number of special characters like *\~;(%?.:@/
That password is then used as a parameter for a .exe command, but it is often incorrect due to some special characters not being escaped properly.

An example past password was $(?-.?-(. The only characters I needed to escape was '(', which I replaced with '`(' to make it work. However, that password is now expired. The new password is something like *\~;~(%?.:@/
*NOTE: these passwords have random numbers and letters mixed into them as well, but have been redacted.

The only characters in the new password NOT in the first are *\~;%:@/
Is there an easy way to escape all characters and just take any user input as it is? If not, would someone mind helping me escape these special characters?

---

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$password
)
```

The above code prefaces the script, causing the console to prompt for user input.

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "<path_to_exe> -install $user $password"
```

^this is the command that uses that password parameter

---

I have tried many other suggestions on Stack Overflow, Reddit, and other various coding forums/blogs and none have worked. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a full list of characters you need to escape?

Comment: Please show the code handling/setting that password. We cannot tell you how (or if) you need to escape anything without seeing that.

Comment: @Drew *\~;~(%?.:@/ is the full list of characters I need to escape.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers

param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$password
)

The above code prefaces the script, causing the console to prompt for user input.

Invoke-Expression -Command "<path_to_exe> -install $user $password"

^this is the command that uses that password parameter

Comment: [Don't use `Invoke-Expression`.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) `& 'C:\path\to\your.exe' -install $user $password` will do what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You're using `Invoke-Expression` to call an external program**:

- **There's *no*  reason to do that**, and [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/): it causes quoting headaches (as in your case), but, more importantly, it can be a security risk and there are typically better solutions.

  - As an aside: Unfortunately, even with direct invocation there can be quoting challenges around empty-string arguments and arguments with *embedded* `"` chars. - see footnote [1] and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).
- **If you instead invoke the external program *directly*** - as any shell, including PowerShell is designed to do - **your problem will likely go away**:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
& <path_to_exe> -install $user $password
```

Note: `&`, PowerShell's [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-), is only needed if your executable's path is quoted (e.g, `"C:\Program Files\foo.exe"`) and/or is specified via a *variable* reference (e.g., `$HOME\foo.exe`); otherwise, you can invoke the executable as-is (e.g., to invoke `cmd.exe`, use something like 
`cmd /c 'echo hi'`).

---

Separately, **if you do ever find yourself needing to escape any of the characters in a *set* of characters, use `-replace` with a [*character class*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character-classes), `[...]`**:

**Note**: This is *not* necessary for passing arguments, neither to external programs, as shown above, nor to PowerShell commands; however, due to PowerShell's broken handling of `"` characters embedded in argument values passed to *external programs*, you may have to escape `"` characters (only), as `\"`<sup>[1]</sup>.

```bash
PS> 'a*b\c~d;e(f%g?h.i:j@k/l' -replace '[*\\~;(%?.:@/]', '`$&'
a`*b`\c`~d`;e`(f`%g`?h`.i`:j`@k`/l  # all chars. inside [...] were `-escaped
```

<sup>Note: Since `\` has special meaning even inside a character class, it had to be escaped as `\\` - all other chars. are used as-is.</sup>

For more information about the `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

---

<sup>[1] There is *one* character that still causes problems: embedded `"`. For historical reasons, PowerShell does *not* properly pass embedded `"` correctly to *external programs*, and annoyingly requires *manual* `\`-*escaping* in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) versions up to v7.2.x - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details.
Applied to your solution:`& <path_to_exe> -install $user ($password -replace '"', '\"'`)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Using the below will escape the characters using the escape prefix you mentioned. The normal escape prefix is \ as shown below. I have set it this way so it is easier for you to add additional characters to escape or change the escape prefix.

```
function Set-EscapeCharacters {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [String]
        $string
    )
    $string = $string -replace '\*', '`*'
    $string = $string -replace '\\', '`\'
    $string = $string -replace '\~', '`~'
    $string = $string -replace '\;', '`;'
    $string = $string -replace '\(', '`('
    $string = $string -replace '\%', '`%'
    $string = $string -replace '\?', '`?'
    $string = $string -replace '\.', '`.'
    $string = $string -replace '\:', '`:'
    $string = $string -replace '\@', '`@'
    $string = $string -replace '\/', '`/'
    $string
}

$Password = Set-EscapeCharacters $Password
```

Comment: I suspect Enoch's escaping problem will go away if the target program is invoked directly rather than - needlessly - via `Invoke-Expression`. Aside from that, it's simpler and more efficient to use a _single_ `-replace` operation with a character set (`[...]`). Quibble: `[Regex]::Escape()` escapes _regex_ metacharacters, which has nothing to do with _PowerShell_.