# To invoke expression when Dynamic variable assigned not working

Tags: powershell

My task is to connect to other VM and execute certain task,.... with task parameters to be passed. i used Invoke-Expression for that,.....
now when i pass static path directly in invoke-expression working fine but when I assign same to varible and appending to invoke-expression. it's not working

I tried by giving static path it's working fine and executing batch on remote vm, problem is when path is dynamic

```
  Static is working fine has shown below:

  $server="slc10XXX.XX.XXXX.com"
  $username="XXXXXXX"
  $password="XXXXXX@321"
  $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force
  $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - 
  ArgumentList $username, $pass
  $path="cmd.exe /c C:\Task6-MASSUOW\chay.bat"
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop 
  -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c C:\Task6- 
  MASSUOW\chay.bat"}

  Getting issue in below code when i assign $path:

  $server="slc10XXX.XX.XXXX.com"
  $username="XXXXXXX"
  $password="XXXXXX@321"
  $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force
  $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - 
  ArgumentList $username, $pass
  $path="cmd.exe /c C:\Task6-MASSUOW\chay.bat"
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop 
  -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"$path"}
```

> PowerShell.exe : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because
>   it is null. At line:1 char:1
>   + PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\Users\chaj\Documents ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Cannot bind arg...use it is null.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   At C:\Users\chaj\Documents\String\Chat1.ps1:8 char:1
>   + Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -credential $cred -ErrorAction S ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpre
>   ssionCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : slc10XXXX.XX.XXXX.com

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `"$path"` is sent as a string literal to the remote server. The expression will be evaluated there, but `$path` was not defined in the remote session. That's why it's null.

You can do this for example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
   param($path)
   Invoke-Expression -Command:$path
} -ArgumentList "cmd.exe /c C:\Task6-MASSUOW\chay.bat"
```

Or simpler:

```
Invoke-Command -Script { & $Args[0] } -Arg "C:\Task6-MASSUOW\chay.bat" -Computer $server -Cred $cred -EA Stop
```

Comment: Don't forget the `$using:` scope as a simpler alternative (PSv3+).