# PowerShell function not running as expected

Tags: powershell, cmd, batch-processing

I have a curious case that I cannot fathom the reason for...

Please know I am a novice to PowerShell.

I am working on a PowerShell menu system to help automate building out new computers in my environment. I have a PS1 file that holds the script for an app install. When I use the script to reference this I am able to run it and have no issue. However, when I try inserting this into a function and referencing it does not.

This works:

```
4       #   Microsoft Office 32-bit
            {
                Write-Host "`nMicrosoft Office 32-bit..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

                # {installMS32Bit}
                Invoke-Expression "cmd /c start powershell -NoExit -File '\\**SERVERPATH**\menuItems\ms_office\32-bit\install.ps1'"

                Start-Sleep -seconds 2
            }
```

This does not:

```
function installMS32Bit(){

Invoke-Expression "cmd /c start powershell -NoExit -File '\\**SERVERPATH**\menuItems\ms_office\32-bit\install.ps1'"
}
```

}

```
4       #   Microsoft Office 32-bit
            {
                Write-Host "`nMicrosoft Office 32-bit..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

                {installMS32Bit}

                Start-Sleep -seconds 2}
```

install.ps1 file:

```
    # Copy MS Office uninstall and setup to local then run and install 32-bit Office
Copy-Item -Path '\\**SERVERPATH**\menuItems\ms_office\setup.exe' -Destination 'C:\temp\' -Force
Copy-Item -Path '\\**SERVERPATH**\menuItems\ms_office\uninstall.xml' -Destination 'C:\temp\' -Force
Copy-Item -Path '\\**SERVERPATH**\menuItems\ms_office\32-bit\Setup.exe' -Destination 'C:\temp' -Force

Invoke-Expression ("cmd /c 'C:\temp\setup.exe' /configure 'C:\temp\uninstall.xml'")

Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\temp\Setup.exe'
```

Secondary question and a little explanation for Invoke-Expression...

I like to see progress and like to have secondary windows open to monitor the new process being run. I was unable to find a solution with a persistent window that worked for me to do this without Invoke-Expression.

If there is a better way to do this in PowerShell I am all ears!

Comment: `{installMS32Bit}` -> `installMS32Bit` (otherwise you're just defining a new scriptblock without executing it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `{installMS32Bit}`

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out in a comment on the question, this statement doesn't *call* your function, it *wraps it in a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)* (`{ ... }`)<sup>[1]</sup>, which is a piece of reusable code (like a function pointer, loosely speaking), for *later* execution via `&`, the [call (execute) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).

To *call* your function, *just use its name* (by itself here, given that there are no *arguments* to pass): `installMS32Bit`

**[`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375)**, as in your attempts.

Additionally, there's **generally no need to call an external program *via `cmd.exe`* (`cmd /c ...`)**, just invoke it *directly*.

For instance, replace the last `Invoke-Epression` call from your question with:

```
# If the EXE path weren't quoted, you wouldn't need the &
& 'C:\temp\setup.exe' /configure 'C:\temp\uninstall.xml'
```

> I like to see progress and like to have secondary windows open to monitor the new process being run. I was unable to find a solution with a persistent window that worked for me to do this without Invoke-Expression.

**(On Windows), [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) *by default* executes a console application in a *new window* (unless you specify `-NoNewWindow`), *asynchronously* (unless you specify `-Wait`).**

You cannot pass a `.ps1` script *directly* to `Start-Process` (it will be treated like a *document* to open rather than an *executable* to call), but you can pass it to [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) via the `-File` parameter:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe '-File install.ps1'
```

The above is short for:

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-File install.ps1'
```

That is, PowerShell will execute the following *in a new window*:
`powershell.exe -File install.ps1`

---

<sup>[1] Since you're not assigning the script block being created to a variable, it is implicitly *output* (printed to the display, in the absence of a redirection); a script block stringifies by its literal contents, excluding the enclosing `{` and `}`, so string `installMS32Bit` will print to the display.</sup>

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed. The suggestion by Mathias and your definition solved that dilemma.

I cannot tell you how long I looked and all the different examples for the Start-Process. None of the sites clarified to put -File into the argument list with the filepath of the ps1. This has completely solved my issues!