# How to run cmd command using powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, jmeter

I am trying to run cmd command using Powershell.

**CMD**

```
cd C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin
jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl
```

**Powershell**

```
$command = @'
cmd.exe /C C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl
'@

Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
```

**Error**

```
cmd.exe : The term 'cmd.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: In short: [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375). Additionally, there's generally no need to call an external program via `cmd.exe` (`cmd /c ...`), just invoke it directly.

Comment: It's a moot point, because invoking `C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl` as-is solves your problem, but your symtpom can't be explained with the code you've posted.

Comment: The two commands in CMD -> runs perfectly using command line. I am just trying to merge the two-line into one and want to run through Powershell.

Comment: Then use the command from my previous comment _as is_ - no need for the ill-advised `Invoke-Expression` or any other cmdlets. PowerShell is a _shell_ - that means it can invoke external programs _directly_ - see the linked post for more information.

Comment: Thanks. but in that case, i am facing error -> Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2

Comment: That is an _unrelated_ problem; it is evidence that the call worked in principle, but that the program you're calling cannot locate `java.exe`; the one difference between your `cmd` command and what you tried in PowerShell is that you didn't `cd` to `C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin` first in PowerShell, so perhaps that is the reason - simply run `cd C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin` in PowerShell first as well (`cd` in PowerShell is a built-in alias for the `Set-Location` cmdlet).

Comment: no luck. same error. should I post a new question for this?

Comment: Please do, and please use the direct-invocation method I suggested, along with what `gcm java.exe` shows in PowerShell and how `%PATH%` in `cmd.exe` differs from `$env:Path` in PowerShell.