# Using current directory as output file for Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to have powershell spit out the output file from a command to the current folder as I am trying to create a printer migration that can be run from a USB stick.

My command is simply: `C:\Windows\System32\spool\tools\Printbrm.exe /b /f C:\Temp\Print`

but I want the file to save to the directory that the script is being run from which can very between D: and and E: because the USB path changes on different computers in our organization.

Anyone able to help with this? I am guessing it is simple but can't figure it out.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot`, returns the path the script is saved at/ran from.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path containing the executing script from `$MyInvocation`:

```
$scriptFolder = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path -Parent
```

If you want the folder from which you're invoked it (since the title says "current directory"):

```
$currentFolder = (Get-Location).Path
```

To run your command and have it dump the output where the script is running:

```
$scriptFolder = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path -Parent
$printArgs = @("/b", "/f", $scriptFolder)
& "C:\Windows\System32\spool\tools\Printbrm.exe" $printArgs
```

Comment: How would I implement that then? Adding that after the /f on the script doesn't work.

Comment: Added example - use `Invoke-Expression` to "run a string".

Comment: [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).