# Powershell Select-Object: Executing native commands in calculated property

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create  a report file which lists all files in my Git repository with these columns:

- Name
- Size
- Last Modified
- Git Commit

The first 3 are no problem:

```
gci -File -Recurse | Select-Object -Property @{
 label = 'Size(KB)'
 expr = { [string]::Format("{0:0.00}", $_.Length/1KB) }
}, LastWriteTime, FullName
```

However,  retrieving the git commit requires running Git, a native command.

I've tried, among others:

```
gci -File -Recurse | Select-Object -Property @{
 label = 'Git commit'
  expr = { Invoke-Expression "git log -1 --format:format=`"%s`" -- $($_.FullName)" }
},
@{
 label = 'Size(KB)'
 expr = { [string]::Format("{0:0.00}", $_.Length/1KB) }
}, LastWriteTime, FullName
```

But it just gets stuck.

Does anyone know how to do this??

P.S.
All the flags and options to Git doesn't matter for the manner of sake, I just copied what I already did.

Comment: Generally speaking: [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Comment: Option `--format:format="%s"` doesn't look right; it should be `--format=format:"%s"`. (PowerShell will strip the `"`, but that shouldn't make a difference.) Therefore, does it work if you replace the `Invoke-Expression` command with the following? `git log -1 --format=format:"%s" -- $_.FullName`

Comment: It's now implied by the answer that you've accepted, but let me spell it out: the `git` options made all the difference, because the syntactically invalid `git` command then produces only _stderr_ output, which in the context of calculated properties is _quietly discarded_, so you'll end up with an empty `Git commit`  output column. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mklement0 suggested in the comments, the issue was just that your formatting for the `--format` command was off just enough to cause a problem.

You had:

```
 --format:format="%s"  # won't work
 --format=format:"%s"  # works
```

So to fix it, we just swap in the right format, giving us this command with the output below.

```
gci -File | Select-Object -Property @{
 label = 'Git commit'
  expr = { Invoke-Expression "git log -1 --format=format:`"%s`" $($_.Name)" }
},
@{
 label = 'Size(KB)'
 expr = { [string]::Format("{0:0.00}", $_.Length/1KB) }
}, LastWriteTime, FullName

Git commit             Size(KB) LastWriteTime         FullName                        
----------             -------- -------------         --------                        
applied gitingore      6.07     5/11/2020 11:22:06 AM C:\git\ClientFaux\.gitignore    
cleanin up layout      1.40     10/9/2020 3:20:33 PM  C:\git\ClientFaux\ClientFaux.sln
Create LICENSE (#25)   34.98    7/13/2020 9:55:00 AM  C:\git\ClientFaux\LICENSE       
Update README.md (#27) 3.37     7/13/2020 9:55:00 AM  C:\git\ClientFaux\README.md     
                       31.13    7/13/2020 9:55:27 AM  C:\git\ClientFaux\UpgradeLog.htm
```

Answer (score 2):

[FoxDeploy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67284017/45375) contains the crucial pointer, but let me offer a (corrected) **PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation of your code**.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Select-Object -Property @{
    label = 'Git commit'
    expr = { git log -1 --format=format:%s -- $_.FullName }
  },
  @{
    label = 'Size(KB)'
    expr = { '{0:0.00}' -f ($_.Length/1KB) }
  }, LastWriteTime, FullName
```

Note:

- **[`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375)**, so the above uses *direct invocation* of `git`.
- As mentioned, `--format:format="%s"` is syntactically incorrect and should be `--format=format:"%s"` (I've omitted the `"` above, which PowerShell would strip behind the scenes anyway).
- `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), is used as the PowerShell-idiomatic alternative to directly calling the underlying .NET API, [`System.String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Format).

---

**Calling native executables in calculated properties**:

*Generally*, note that there's nothing *fundamentally* special about calling native executables from the `expression` [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) of a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties).

*Specifically*, the following considerations apply:

- In PowerShell, *stdout* output from native executables is invariably converted to *text* (`[string]` instances). If the output comprises *multiple lines*, the property values becomes a (regular `[object[]]`) *array* containing strings.

  - If the native executable produces no *stdout* output, the value of the property is "nothing", i.e. the so-called "Automation Null" value (`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`) that in most context behaves like `$null`.
- Any *stderr* output from the native executable is *quietly discarded*. (Analogously, errors from *PowerShell* commands or expressions in `expression` script blocks are quietly ignored.)

Therefore, **in order to *troubleshoot* an `expression` script block, execute it *stand-alone***, via a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) command (whose built-in alias is `%`), **so as to surface any errors**; e.g.:

```
# Uses broken `git` syntax; note the resulting error message.
PS> (Get-ChildItem -File)[0] | % { git log -1 --format:format=%s -- $_.FullName } 
fatal: unrecognized argument: --format:format=%s
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

Because your `git` command was syntactically incorrect, `git` only produced *stderr* output, which PowerShell then *ignored*, as explained above.

Thus, your `Git commit` properties ended up containing "nothing", which simply renders blank in output formatting.

Comment: Great answer!  This part especially `Therefore, in order to troubleshoot an expression script block, execute it stand-alone, via a ForEach-Object command (whose built-in alias is %), so as to surface any errors; e.g.:
`