# Catching script-terminating errors only in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception

PowerShell 5.1

I've written a wrapper script that launches another script, logs its output (via Start-Transcript), sends an email if it exited with a non-zero code, and finally rotates the log file based on file size.

I only want to catch errors that would cause the called script to exit when executed on its own.
(*Script-terminating* term based on the discussion here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

```
try { 
    Invoke-Expression "& '$Script' $ArgList"
    $err = $LastExitCode
} catch { 
    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
    $err = 1
}
```

Catch this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Remove-Item -Path DoesntExist
```

or this:

```
throw "Error"
```

But not this (script should continue executing as it would if not called via the logging script):

```
Test-Path -Foo bar
```

Is it possible? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: instead of define the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable, set it in the cmdlet, for example ignore the error for `Test-Path -Foo bar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and use it for the `Remove-Item -Path DoesntExist -ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: I want the called script to behave like it would when executed on its own. In this example, `Test-Path` fails but the script keeps running. But when I call it via my wrapper script, it catches that exception and stops.

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A [`try { ... } catch { ... }` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) makes no distinction between a *statement*-terminating (`Test-Path -Foo bar`) and a *script*-terminating error (`throw "Error"`)**: *both* sub-types of *terminating* errors trigger the `catch` block.

In other words: Any intrinsically *statement*-terminating error, such as `1 / 0` or `Test-Path -Foo bar` (an invocation-syntax error, because there is no such parameter) will invariably *also* trigger your `catch` block.

So will any *non-terminating* error that is *promoted to* a *script*-terminating one, either with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` or `-ErrorAction Stop` (which is what you want).

- As an aside: `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` - unlike `-ErrorAction Stop` - will also promote *statement*-terminating errors to *script*-terminating ones, which is just one of the problematic aspects of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling, discussed in detail in the [GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) linked to in your question.

---

Related information (which won't solve your problem):

With respect to *post-mortem* error analysis, the best you can do to analyze *what kind* of error occurred is to check if it was a script-terminating one *triggered by a `throw` statement*, by examining `$_.Exception.WasThrownFromThrowStatement`, but you won't generally be able to distinguish between a statement-terminating error, a non-terminating error, and a non-terminating error promoted to a script-terminating one.

[GitHub issue #4781](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4781) discusses a potential future improvement for detecting the *intrinsic* vs. *effective* "fatality" of an error.