# in Powershell, how to pass $args of type string[] to a "function param()" (I dont want to pass a @{} of type Hashtable to the function)

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, how to pass $args of type string[] to a "function param()"... see code below, it doesn't work...

(Note: I dont want to  pass a hash @{} of type Hashtable to the function as required by splatting.  I want to pass a string[] type as arguments to function param)...

```
# FILE: run1.ps1
function run1{
   param(
       [switch]$go,
       [string]$sim,
       [switch]$rec
   )
   
   write-host "go:  $go"
   write-host "sim: $sim"
   write-host "rec: $rec"   
}


write-host ""
foreach ($a in $args) {
    write-host "a: $a"  
}
write-host ""

run1 $args
```

```
PS> ./run1.ps1

a: -go
a: -rec:
a: dfsdf
a: -rec

go:  False
sim: -go -rec: dfsdf -rec
rec: False
```

Comment: how to do this using "&" or invoke-command?  I tried splatting an Array instead of a hashtable and its flakey... and doesn't work with ps2exe....

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of `run1 $args`, use `run1 @args`**, i.e. [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) with the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args).

That way, whatever arguments are passed to the `run1.ps1` *script* - whether named or positional - are correctly passed through to the `run1` *function*.

- *Caveat*: This does *not* work for pass-through `[switch]` arguments *with an explicit value* (which is rare, however). For instance, if you were to invoke `run1.ps1` with `-rec:$false` (instead of simply *omitting* this argument), `-rec` and `$false` would mistakenly be passed as *two* arguments, and `$rec` would end up being `$true`.

Note:

- No *user-defined* array can provide this functionality<sup>[1]</sup> - the automatic `$args` array has magic built in that enables this functionality; splatting with a user-defined array only supports passing *positional* arguments through, and that wouldn't work in your case, because `[switch]` parameters are always *named* (non-positional).
- For splatting based on user-defined variables that supports passing *named* arguments, [*hashtable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)-based splatting is necessary.

As an aside:

- If you make your function an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one (in the simplest case by decorating the `param(...)` block with `[CmdletBinding()]`), it'll ensure that no *extra* arguments are passed (ones that don't bind to predefined parameters), for added robustness.
- If you additionally make your *script* an advanced one - which requires defining parameters explicitly for the script itself too - you can pass the script's parameter values through via the [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) variable, i.e. with `run1 @PSBoundParameters`. This would also avoid the `[switch]`-related bug mentioned above. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71075060/45375) shows an example of `$PSBoundParameters`-based splatting in the context of a proxy (wrapper) function around `Write-Host`.

---

<sup>[1] As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, there a *limited* way to make this work, but it is both highly obscure and more cumbersome than using a *hashtable* for splatting and therefore not worth considering.

For the sake of completeness: To have an array element represent a parameter *name*, use a dummy string decorated with a NoteProperty member literally named `<CommandParameterName>` whose value is the target parameter name (with or without the `-` prefix). A minimal example that is the equivalent of

`Get-ChildItem -Directory -LiteralPath \`:

`$arr = ('' | Add-Member -PassThru '<CommandParameterName>' 'Directory'), ('' | Add-Member -PassThru '<CommandParameterName>' 'LiteralPath'), '\'; Get-ChildItem @arr`

In fact, this technique is behind the magic of `@args`, as the following example shows:

`` function foo { $args | % { "`n---`n[$_]"; $_ | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty -Force } }; foo -param1 val1 ``</sup>

Answer (score -1):

```
function run1{
   param(
       [switch]$go,
       [string]$sim,
       [switch]$rec
   )
   
   write-host "go:  $go"
   write-host "sim: $sim"
   write-host "rec: $rec"   
}

$cmd = "run1 $args"
write-host "cmd: $cmd"
invoke-expression "$cmd"
```

```
PS> run1.ps1 -go -sim:asdfasdf +rec


PS> run1.ps1 -go -sim:asdfasdf -rec
```

Comment: [`Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script / function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Comment: A simple example that shows that your approach isn't robust: `run1.ps1 -go -sim:'foo bar' -rec` doesn't bind `-sim` correctly (only binds `foo` as the value).

Comment: Also, PowerShell `[switch]` parameters don't support syntax such as `+rec`. Pass `-rec` to set `$rec` to `$true`, and _omit it_ to default to `$false`. If you need to _explicitly_ pass the switch value, use `-rec:$true` or `-rec:$false` (which also wouldn't work with your `Invoke-Expression` approach). Your `+rec` argument was simply _ignored_, because it didn't bind to any declared parameter (but it would have been reflected in `$args`). If your function  were an advanced one, you would have gotten a _syntax error_.