# Start new shell not working when the ps1 has become executable with ps2exe

Tags: powershell, ps2exe-gui

I am trying to create an executable (.exe) at windows that will perform some actions at first, and then open an interactive shell. In my case the interactive shell I want to be a wsl, but the problem is shown with every type of shells created.
For example:

Supposing that we have the file

**test.ps1**

```
Write-Host "Hello from my test program"
Invoke-Expression "powershell"
```

If I run it with the command: `./test.ps1`, the outcome will be to print the message and start a new powershell instance.
If i run the command: `Invoke-ps2exe .\test.ps1 test.exe`, and then run the `test.exe`, the outcome will be:

```
Hello from my test program
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
```

but I cannot write anything at the window.
Can anyone explain me why this is happening, and how I could overcome this?

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `test.ps1` file as follows:

```
Write-Host "Hello from my test program"
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow powershell.exe
```

This change ensures that PowerShell's usual interactive host, `ConsoleHost`, in the newly launched PowerShell session launched from your script doesn't run *on top of* the simplified host that is built into the `.exe` files that `ps2exe` generates, which appears to cause your problems.