# Powershell Where-Object and BitLocker

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I've got a powershell script where the end goal is to just print the BitLocker Recovery Key to a text file, but I want to use the Where-Object to get only the RecoveryPassword, as opposed to the TPM information.

If I run the last line, it works fine. If I try to run the command passed to a variable, I get an error stating ".KeyProtectorType : The term '.KeyProtectorType' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

I think it's some issue with directory changing because it's being passed in a variable, but I do not know how to work around it.

```
$location = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\BitLockerRecoveryKey.txt"

$args = "Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C:| Select-Object -ExpandProperty KeyProtector | Where-Object{$_.KeyProtectorType -eq 'RecoveryPassword'}| Select-Object KeyProtectorID,RecoveryPassword >"  + $location
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account

iex $args
Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C:| Select-Object -ExpandProperty KeyProtector | Where-Object{$_.KeyProtectorType -eq 'RecoveryPassword'}| Select-Object KeyProtectorID,RecoveryPassword
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375), even if you need to construct its arguments *programmatically* - the latter is best done via [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting).
- Don't use the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) for *custom* purposes.
- If you do need to embed `$` characters *verbatim* in a [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), escape them as `` `$ ``. If you string doesn't actually require expansion (string interpolation), use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)

  - Neglecting to escape the `$` characters as `` `$ `` in your `"..."` string is what caused your problem: `$_` was expanded *before* `iex` saw the resulting string, and - outside a pipeline - the automatic `$_` variable doesn't have a value.

---

In your case, you can use the value of variable `$location` *directly* to pass the output file path to `>`, the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection)

```bash
$location = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\BitLockerRecoveryKey.txt"

Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C:|
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty KeyProtector |
  Where-Object KeyProtectorType -eq RecoveryPassword | 
  Select-Object KeyProtectorID, RecoveryPassword > $location
```

Note that I've used [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) in the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call above.