# Foreach parallel Missing an argument for parameter 'xxx'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object' and try again

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

i'm using a parallel foreach in a powershell script. I'm getting a problem to pass external variable inside the loop. The code is following

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $var1,
    $var2,
    $var3,
    $var4
)


$MyArr | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
 
   
      Invoke-Expression ".\myscript.ps1 -var1 $var1 -var2 $var2 -var3 $var3 -var4 $var4"


}
```

when execute it i'm getting

myscript.ps1: Missing an argument for parameter 'var1'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object' and try again.

There is a way to fix it?

REgards
Thanks

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`using:` special scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) to make PowerShell copy the values to the underlying runspace:

```
$MyArr | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    .\myscript.ps1 -var1 $using:var1 -var2 $using:var2 -var3 $using:var3 -var4 $using:var4
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I modified it but i'm getting this error now:

Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.

i put $using:var1 as your advice

Comment: @Emanuele The error indicates that something else is immediately following `:`, make sure you didn't include any whitespace eg. `$using: var1` - it has to be `$using:var1` or `${using:var1}` exactly

Comment: Thanks, i think i miss something. Now foreach run but i think that the variable that i pass to the other script are empty. Seems that $using is not working and vars are empty

Comment: @Emanuele you might be able to splat on `$PSBoundParameters` just sayin :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon `$PSBoundParameters` inside the loop body will have been overwritten

Comment: sorry guys i never user $PSBoundParameters , can you please make an example? Just to understand

Comment: Hi all, was my mistake. I solved this morning. Thanks