# Use PowerShell script to run WSL command

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can manually open up PowerShell and run

```
wsl
ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet\b' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

To get the IP address of the Ubuntu instance. But when I try to write a script for this (100 different ways) I always get some kind of error. This is an example

```
$command = "ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet\b' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1"
$ip = Invoke-Expression "wsl $command"
```

Which gives an error about `grep`.

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `wsl.exe` via the `-e` option and specify `bash` as the executable, which allows you to use the latter's `-c` option with a command line specified as a single string:

```bash
# Note the need to escape $ as `$ 
# to prevent PowerShell from interpolating it up front inside "..."
$command = "ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet\b' | awk '{print `$2}' | cut -d/ -f1"

wsl -e bash -c $command
```

---

A note re the *choice of string literals* on the PowerShell side:

- Using `"..."` quoting rather than `'...'` quoting is *convenient* if the text contains `'` characters, because it obviates the need for *escaping* - ditto for the *inverse* scenario: using `'...'` quoting for text that contains `"` chars.
- However, as in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash, *the choice of the enclosing quoting characters matters* in PowerShell, because the resulting behavior differs:

  - `'...'` is a [verbatim (single-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings).

    - Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells, where escaping embedded `'` chars. must be *emulated* with `'\''`, PowerShell *does* support direct escaping, namely with `''`
  - `"..."` is an [expandable (double-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), i.e. subject to *string interpolation* for substrings that start with `$`

    - Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells, where embedded `$` chars. to be used *verbatim* (literally) require escaping as `\$`, in PowerShell you must use `` `$ ``, using `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters).

Comment: Pretty much works. What's weird is that when entering the command directly into the WSL shell or via PowerShell, I get the IP address. However with this, when I save it to a variable, I get `inet a.b.c.d` ie I for some reason I get the "inet " string as well.

Comment: @radop33392, escaping `$2` as `\`$2` fixes that problem, as the updated answer now explains. Without it, `$2` expands to the _empty string_, which explains the symptom.

Answer (score 1):

Or let's assume you have powershell installed in linux (there's no Get-NetIPConfiguration?).

```
$command = "ip addr show eth0 | select-string inet\b | % { (-split `$_)[1] } |
   % { (`$_ -split '/')[0] }"
wsl -e pwsh -c $command

10.0.0.107
```

Or even without it, piping to windows powershell cmdlets.

```
wsl -e ip addr show eth0 | select-string inet\b | % { (-split $_)[1] } |
  % { ($_ -split '/')[0] }

10.0.0.107
```

$command has to be an array of words:

```
$command = 'ip address show eth0'
wsl -e (-split $command) | select-string inet\b | % { (-split $_)[1] } |
  % { ($_ -split '/')[0] }
```