# Stuck at running commands inside WSL on a windows powershell gitlab runner

Tags: windows, powershell, gitlab, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gitlab-ci-runner

i try to execute commands inside wsl on a windows gitlab runner with a powershell executer. But i cant find a way to creat any outcome.

This was my minimal starting setup that i try to run:

```
qsys-build:
    stage: build     
    script:     
        - wsl -e bash -c "ls"
```

This runs fine and the pipeline succeed but the command is not producing any output.

I then wrote a short `.ps1` script that i execute in the pipeline. Here i pipe the output of the command into a variable and then printing the variable:

```
$wslOutput = wsl -e bash -c 'ls'
Write-Output "wsl -e bash -c 'ls': $wslOutput"
```

This gives me the output: `"wsl -e bash -c 'ls': a c c e s s d e n i e d"`

Then i added my user to the gitlabl runner service inside windows, that the pipeline is executed with my admin rights. This is then only changing from `"access denied"` to an **empty output** again.

When i execute these commands in a powershell directly all commands are fine. So there need to be any trick or misconfiguration?

I already serched throught many diffent threads and even discussed with chatGPT and phind.com without any luck.

So i thaught maybe I'm on the wrong track but i can't be the only one trying this (despite the fact that other uses this exact same command without any problems like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998898/use-powershell-script-to-run-wsl-command)).
What is the correct way of using wsl inside a gitlab pipeline or where can i dig into to find the missing part here? Any thaugts or hints what I'm doing wrong is highly appreciated.